# Making a (simple) directory tree

Tags: diagrams, trees

I'm trying to make a simple directory tree representation in LaTeX. Something like:

```
spam
 |
 +-- ham
 +-- eggs
     |
     +-- more spam
     +-- dead parrots
```

The tree won't be that long (say, 10--15 entries or so), with three or so levels, and is a one-off thing. So, quick-and-dirty solutions are welcome. When recommending `tikz`[1](http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree), please note that I have almost no experience with it, so I'd appreciate a clean simple solution, even if it doesn't look quite perfect.

[1](http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree) On Tex.SE `tikz` is almost like the `jquery` recurring joke on StackOverflow..

---

**Edit**: As per Thorsten's suggestion, [dirtree](http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree) is a nice and easy-to-use solution. The example from above could be written as:

```
\usepackage{dirtree}
...
\dirtree{%
.1 spam.
.2 ham.
.2 eggs.
.3 more spam.
.3 dead parrots.
}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121525/how-to-make-directory-list-in-latex/121788#121788 ?

Comment: Came here from Google. After reading the answers and following some references, I ended up using [this answer from another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405253/211230). Leaving this here, as it would have saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The [dirtree](http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree) package is your friend.

Comment: Unfortunately dirtree is in conflict with algorithmic and pseudocode. So it's useless in many cases.

Comment: And one problem, probably not in your case (~15 entries), is that it does not support page breaks.

Comment: can we draw dirtree inside a tikzpicture?

Answer (score 119):

Here's one option using the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package; since its built upon TikZ the customization possibilities are enormous.

For example one can easily simulate the style produced by `dirtree`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
[text1
  [text1.1
    [text1.1.1]
    [text1.1.2]
    [text1.1.3]
  ]
  [text1.2
    [text1.2.1]
    [text1.2.2]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a simple modification to the previous specifications

```
  for tree={
    font=\sffamily,
    text=white,
    text width=2cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm,
    if level=0
      {fill=mygreenii}
      {fill=mygreeni},
    rounded corners=4pt,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge={mygreenii,rounded corners,line width=1pt},
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    s sep=15pt,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
```

now gives:

[image]

The initial theme can also be easily changed to

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}

\def\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{
  folder/.pic={
    \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
      (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);  
    \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
      (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    inner xsep=7pt,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor) pic {folder} \forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }  
[system
  [config
  ]
  [lib
    [Access
    ]
    [Plugin
    ]
  ]
  [templates
  ]
  [tests
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

which produced

[image]

And combining these settings with a variation of [`my answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211736/3954) to [Draw directory tree using folder icons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211726/3954) one can produce

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\definecolor{fblue}{RGB}{92,144,192}
\definecolor{fgreen}{RGB}{34,162,70}

\newcommand\myfolder[2][fblue]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\begin{scope}[xshift=20pt]
\filldraw[rounded corners=1pt,fill=#1,draw=white,double=black]
  (-23pt,10pt) -- ++(3pt,5pt) -- ++(18pt,0pt) -- ++(40:3pt) -- ++(9pt,0pt) -- ++(-40:3pt)
  -- (20pt,15pt) -- (23pt,10pt) -- cycle;
\filldraw[rounded corners,draw=white,double=black,top color=#1,bottom color=#1!30]
  (-22pt,-12pt) -- ++(44pt,0pt) -- (25pt,12pt) coordinate (topr) -- ++(-50pt,0pt) coordinate (topl) -- cycle;
\end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}%
\makebox[35pt]{\raisebox{-3pt}{{\ttfamily/#2}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\sffamily,
    minimum height=0.75cm,
    rounded corners=4pt,
    grow'=0,
    inner ysep=8pt,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge={rounded corners},
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(12.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom,minimum height=18pt]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    s sep=12pt,
    before computing xy={l=25pt},
  }
[\myfolder{}
  [\myfolder{bin}]
  [\myfolder{dev}]
  [{\myfolder[fgreen]{home}}
    [{\myfolder[fgreen]{anna}}]
    [{\myfolder[fgreen]{tess}}]
  ]
  [\myfolder{media}]
  [\myfolder{mnt}]
  [\myfolder{usr}]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What should be noticed here is that once the basic specification for the vertical structure has been established (which I borrowed with some modifications from **cfr** (See, for example [`her answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269820/3954) to [how to adjust large number of nodes in forest environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269734/3954))):

```
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
```

all one has to do is to let the imagination fly and produce as many variations as desired using the power of `forest`/TikZ.

Comment: Awesome answer. Just out of curiosity, is this a new package? Cause the question is ~5 years old.

Comment: @Rakesh I have started a bounty on the question to draw some attention to it. My motivation for the bounty is that a [recent question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270747/how-can-i-make-a-picture-of-this-tree) was closed as a duplicate of this one, but I didn't find the answers here satisfactory.

Comment: @yo' What other kind of variation/customization would you like to see?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I like it as a proof of concept. Once it's clear you can easily do it with `forest`, everybody can use any customization this package offers to provide the result. Awesome answer!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Does it have any 'folder' structure (like the last one you added) that is little bit subtler. Like something that we see in 'Windows Explorer' and in 'Mac's Finder'? I mean to ask, the text follows the icon, and not inside that

Comment: @Rakesh Since the power of TikZ is at hand, one could create any desired shape (like I did with the folders in my last example). Do you have a link to an image of the kind of "folder" structure you want? (I can take a look at it, but I don't promise I will recreate it).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Nothing specific. I was just wondering whether a folder structure similar to the ones that we see in the Windows and Mac is possible without much hassle. I don't need it, I was just curious. The vanilla structure (the first one in your answer) suits my taste. Thanks again!

Comment: @Rakesh I see. I added another possible variation that perhaps is closer to what you initially had in mind.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I had in mind

Comment: It might be easier to define a style as I do [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/drawing-a-directory-listing-a-la-the-tree-command-in-tikz/249215#249215)? I think I answered one or two questions like this and then created a style for a couple because this isn't the easiest layout to get right in `forest`. At least, not for me and I found it easier to have it on-hand ready-made. This would also separate the structure from the flights of imagination ;).

Comment: @cfr SOunds like a good idea. Tomorrow I'll do some tests to see how versatile is the style definition and I will decide whether to use it or not. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how it might work. I'd be interested in what you work out, though. (Whether a style or not.)

Comment: I seem to have perfect time, exactly when I start looking for it someone writes this awesome answer :)

Comment: I've provided an updated version of one of the solutions here at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328987/ . I would strongly recommend that users looking for this kind of tree now use the facilities of Forest's new `edges` library. The icons etc. are an invaluable addition, but the basic structure would now be more robustly provided by the `folder` style. (Not to be confused with Gonzalo Medina's `folder` icon!!)

Comment: This is awesome @Gonzalo Medina . Is there any easy way to decrease the vertical space between nodes in the first example? I have tried `node distance` and `l sep=` to no avil. A bit of a newbie to forest/TikZ. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind. I found my answer. I needed to set ``inner sep =0`` to get a more vertically, compact layout. Thnaks!

Comment: It is probably worth to checkout the solution of the following link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405192/how-to-insert-folder-icon-in-root-node-with-forest-package

Comment: how can i add 2 lines in one node? please help.

Comment: can `folder`  picture's background be white?

Answer (score 16):

Following @cfr's lead: a rewrite of one of [Gonzalo Medina's trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270761/) but with an option to put files inside the tree as well. Just call the option `is file` for the file nodes. Also the folder `pic` now takes one argument which is the folder icon size, making possible to emphasize a specific folder by calling `this folder size=<dim>`. The key `folder tree indent=<dim>` sets how much *the icon* goes inside the tree and `folder indent=<dim>` sets how much after the icon *the line* comes from.

The style `folder icons` (or `folder icons=<dim>`) is defined on top of the `folder` style from `forest`, the only change made to it was the `edge` path (a `pic` was placed at the end). **Important**: As mentioned by @cfr in the comments using it without `grow'=0` leads to unexpected results. That is due to the fact that the icon is placed at the end of the edge causing the icon and text to overlap, to fix this some extra space `inner xsep` is automatically added by `folder icons`, but if the tree grows vertically than the `xsep` needs to become `ysep`. Do note that using just `sep` would do for both cases but the edge would be too far away from the text making it not so pretty...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\definecolor{foldercolor}{RGB}{124,166,198}

\tikzset{pics/folder/.style={code={%
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum size=#1](-foldericon){};
    \node[folder style, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.3*#1, minimum height=0.6*#1, above right, xshift=0.05*#1] at (-foldericon.west){};
    \node[folder style, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=#1] at (-foldericon.center){};}
    },
    pics/folder/.default={20pt},
    folder style/.style={draw=foldercolor!80!black,top color=foldercolor!40,bottom color=foldercolor}
}

\forestset{is file/.style={edge path'/.expanded={%
        ([xshift=\forestregister{folder indent}]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)},
        inner sep=1pt},
    this folder size/.style={edge path'/.expanded={%
        ([xshift=\forestregister{folder indent}]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor) pic[solid]{folder=#1}}, inner ysep=0.6*#1},
    folder tree indent/.style={before computing xy={l=#1}},
    folder icons/.style={folder, this folder size=#1, folder tree indent=3*#1},
    folder icons/.default={12pt},
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={font=\sffamily, %grow'=0,
    folder indent=.9em, folder icons,
    edge=densely dotted}
    [main folder
      [images, this folder size=20pt
          [wallpapers]
          [logo.pdf, is file]]
      [tex-files
          [chapter1.tex, is file]]
      [main.tex, is file]
      [main.aux, is file]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: With grow'=0]

Now removing the `grow'=0` and replacing `xsep` with `ysep` (there's only one instance of this in the code - also `folder indent` needs to be adjusted):

[image: Vertical growth - needs ysep instead of xsep]

The `main.tex` too close to the edge is because `fit` is set to `tight`, setting it to `band` fixes it but the tree grows larger...

Comment: Nice! I'm not sure how robust the edge path will be with `.expanded`. (I'm not sure it won't be, either.) Did you try `\foresteregister` instead?

Comment: @cfr, I consulted the manual before any trickery was done. That's actually exactly what the `folder` style provided by `forest` does (among other things of course). So I didn't gave any thought to it, just copied pasted. `;P`

Comment: Fair enough. Though `folder` itself has some odd effects. But you can blame Sašo in this case :-).

Comment: If the tree grows in the default direction, something goes very wrong! That is, try commenting out `grow'=0` ...

Comment: Indeed, I've managed to isolate the issues. The weird big spaces between lines and folders is because of the big value I used for `folder indent tree` (mainly for demonstration). The folder text overlapping with the folder Icon was because I used `xsep`, using `sep` instead fixes it but the edges get backed away too, the main Problem in that matter is the folder Icon, it's placed at the end of the edge and if no inner spaced is added the Icon overlaps with the text... I changed some things and added Information about this in the answer. If you find anything else do say! `=D`

Comment: I tried to find a nice fix, too, but didn't produce anything great. I think you've done better ;).

Comment: I would like to show a folder icon for "main folder" (to improve the consistency of the result). Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Found a solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405192/how-to-insert-folder-icon-in-root-node-with-forest-package/405253#405253

Answer (score 13):

Rewrite of one of [Gonzalo Medina's trees above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270761/) for Forest v2 which makes it much easier to draw this kind of tree.

Updated versions of two of the other styles: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361248/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328987/.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  my label/.style={
    label={[font=\sffamily]right:{#1}},
  },
  for tree={% addaswyd o gôd Gonzalo Medina: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270761/
    folder,
    font=\sffamily,
    text=white,
    minimum height=0.75cm,
    text width=20mm,
    if level=0{fill=ForestGreen}{fill/.wrap pgfmath arg={SlateBlue#1}{int(4-(mod((level()-1),4)))}},
    rounded corners=4pt,
    grow'=0,
    edge={ForestGreen,rounded corners,line width=1pt},
    fit=band,
  },
  [text1
    [text1.1
      [text1.1.1
        [text1.1.1.1
          [text1.1.1.1.1]
          [text1.1.1.1.2]
          [text1.1.1.1.3]
        ]
      ]
      [textt1.1.2
        [text1.1.2.1]
      ]
      [text1.1.3
        [text1.1.3.1]
      ]
    ]
    [text1.2
      [text1.2.1]
      [text1.2.2]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: update for v2 of GM's tree]