# Drawing a directory listing a la the tree command in TikZ

Tags: trees, tikz-trees

Good day everyone -

Is there a fast and efficient way to draw directory tree structures (aka depth-indented listings) like the unix's tree command, that is, is there a way to draw the following using TikZ?

```
root
  |
  |--- dir1
  |     |
  |     |-- a1
  |     |-- a2
  |--- dir2
  |--- dir3
```

I've checked tikz-tree and tikz-qtree, but the packages always want to grow the tree balanced and not down then to the right.

Any advice is truly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If TikZ is not really obligatory, then try [dirtree](http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree) package.

Comment: Using TikZ is tricky here: you can get part of the way by using `grow with three children = one child at (2em,-2em) and two children at (2em,-2em) and (2em, -4em)` and `edge from parent` to draw perpendicular lines.  But as the manual says, tree layout occurs without reasoning about the size of the children.  tikz-qtree handles reasoning about the size of the children, and the `grow'=right` option will grow trees rightwards, but balanced instead of bottom-heavy.  So some variant of tikz-qtree's code should work...but I don't understand its code well enough to write that variant.

Answer (score 33):

I just came across this thanks to the duplicate at [Vertical trees with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34216/86).  The following code seems to work, though I will admit to not testing it fully and making up the numbers so that it *just works*.

Let's start with some output:

[image: TikZ version of dirtree]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcount\dirtree@lvl
\newcount\dirtree@plvl
\newcount\dirtree@clvl
\def\dirtree@growth{%
  \ifnum\tikznumberofcurrentchild=1\relax
  \global\advance\dirtree@plvl by 1
  \expandafter\xdef\csname dirtree@p@\the\dirtree@plvl\endcsname{\the\dirtree@lvl}
  \fi
  \global\advance\dirtree@lvl by 1\relax
  \dirtree@clvl=\dirtree@lvl
  \advance\dirtree@clvl by -\csname dirtree@p@\the\dirtree@plvl\endcsname
  \pgf@xa=1cm\relax
  \pgf@ya=-1cm\relax
  \pgf@ya=\dirtree@clvl\pgf@ya
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}}%
  \ifnum\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\tikznumberofchildren
  \global\advance\dirtree@plvl by -1
  \fi
}

\tikzset{
  dirtree/.style={
    growth function=\dirtree@growth,
    every node/.style={anchor=north},
    every child node/.style={anchor=west},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) |- (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)}
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dirtree]
\node {toplevel} 
    child { node {Foo}
            child { node {foo} }
            child { node {bar} }
            child { node {baz} }
    }
    child { node {Bar}
        child { node {foo} }
        child { node {foo} }
        child { node {foo} }
        child { node {foo} }
        child { node {bar} }
        child { node {baz} }
    }
    child { node {Baz}
        child { node {foo} }
        child { node {bar} }
        child { node {baz} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

We define a new growth function.  The idea is that we have a global counter that keeps track of how many nodes we've processed so far and position the children according to this.  The main problem is that the way trees are built: the origin for each branch is the parent node.  So we want to apply an absolute transformation (the total height from the root) but have to take into account the relative transformation first.  This takes a bit of bookkeeping, but once that's figured out then the rest is ... plain sailing.

The edges are the easy bit - we simply define them to be `|-`, ie vertical and then horizontal.

Comment: I’ve added node anchors for better appearance with longer text. There’s also another solution on texample.net, now: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/filesystem-tree/.

Comment: @Speravir Good addition, thanks.  I also agree with your comment on the texample example!  I'm not known for the *elegance* of my code here.  If you can think of any further improvements to make it easier to customise, then feel free to edit the answer (or, if you feel you've done a lot of improving, then add another answer with the improved code).

Comment: Worth noting the modifications from http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89129/86 for better arranging the horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 20):

Here are two concepts doing it with `TikZ`. The first one doesn't draw enough lines, the second one draws too many. I guess one needs counters for each level. Those counters would be increased if the same level occurs again and draw a line to it, while they would reset when a higher level is encounterd, e.g. like one could principally do with

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{leveltwo}{levelone}
```

Probably I'll get to it this week, but don't count on it. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[parskip,14pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{treeline}

\newcommand{\treeroot}[1]{% Title
\node[above] at (0,0) {#1};%
\setcounter{treeline}{0}
}

\newcommand{\treeentry}[2]{% Title, Level
\draw[->] (#2-1,-\value{treeline}/2) -- (#2-1,-\value{treeline}/2-0.5) -- (#2+0.5,-\value{treeline}/2-0.5) node[right] {#1};
\stepcounter{treeline}
}

\newcommand{\altentry}[2]{% Title, Level
\draw[->] (#2-1,-\value{treeline}/2) -- (#2-1,-\value{treeline}/2-0.5) -- (#2+0.5,-\value{treeline}/2-0.5) node[right] {#1};
\foreach \x in {1,...,#2}
{   \draw (\x-1,-\value{treeline}/2) -- (\x-1,-\value{treeline}/2-0.5);
}
\stepcounter{treeline}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\treeroot{$\sqrt{of\ all\ evil}$}
\treeentry{Bla}{1}
\treeentry{Bla}{2}
\treeentry{Bla}{3}
\treeentry{Bla}{2}
\treeentry{Bla}{2}
\treeentry{Bla}{3}
\treeentry{Bla}{3}
\treeentry{Bla}{3}
\treeentry{Bla}{3}
\treeentry{Bla}{3}
\treeentry{Bla}{4}
\treeentry{Bla}{4}
\treeentry{Bla}{4}
\treeentry{Bla}{4}
\treeentry{Bla}{4}
\treeentry{Bla}{4}
\treeentry{Bla}{1}
\treeentry{Bla}{1}
\treeentry{Bla}{2}
\treeentry{Bla}{3}
\treeentry{Bla}{2}
\treeentry{Bla}{2}
\treeentry{Bla}{3}
\treeentry{Bla}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\treeroot{$\sqrt{of\ all\ evil}$}
\altentry{Bla}{1}
\altentry{Bla}{2}
\altentry{Bla}{3}
\altentry{Bla}{2}
\altentry{Bla}{2}
\altentry{Bla}{3}
\altentry{Bla}{3}
\altentry{Bla}{3}
\altentry{Bla}{3}
\altentry{Bla}{3}
\altentry{Bla}{4}
\altentry{Bla}{4}
\altentry{Bla}{4}
\altentry{Bla}{4}
\altentry{Bla}{4}
\altentry{Bla}{4}
\altentry{Bla}{1}
\altentry{Bla}{1}
\altentry{Bla}{2}
\altentry{Bla}{3}
\altentry{Bla}{2}
\altentry{Bla}{2}
\altentry{Bla}{3}
\altentry{Bla}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

**Update: Forest now provides this style more-or-less out-of-the-box. If you need a solution for older versions of Forest (for whatever reason), see my original answer below for the definition of a suitable style.**

---

## Forest v.2

Here's a `forest` solution which uses the `folder` style provided by the `edges` library. This requires version 2 of Forest.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    folder,
    grow'=0,
    fit=band,
  }
  [root
    [bin
    ]
    [etc
      [X11]
      [cron.d]
      [default]
    ]
    [local
      [bin]
      [etc]
      [texlive
        [2014
          [bin]
          [readme-html.dir]
          [texmf-config]
          [texmf-dist]
          [texmf-var]
        ]
        [texmf-local]
      ]
    ]
    [usr
      [bin]
      [include]
      [share]
    ]
    [var
      [cache]
      [log]
      [spool]
      [tmp]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: almost-out-of-the-box with v.2]

## Forest v.1

Here's my original `forest` solution which defines a new style `dir tree` which can be used to typeset trees in this format with version 1 of `forest`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{
  dir tree/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south west,
      child anchor=west,
      anchor=mid west,
      inner ysep=1pt,
      grow'=0,
      align=left,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) ++(1em,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      font=\sffamily,
      if n children=0{}{
        delay={
          prepend={[,phantom, calign with current]}
        }
      },
      fit=band,
      before computing xy={
        l=2em
      }
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  dir tree
  [root
    [bin
    ]
    [etc
      [X11]
      [cron.d]
      [default]
    ]
    [local
      [bin]
      [etc]
      [texlive
        [2014
          [bin]
          [readme-html.dir]
          [texmf-config]
          [texmf-dist]
          [texmf-var]
        ]
        [texmf-local]
      ]
    ]
    [usr
      [bin]
      [include]
      [share]
    ]
    [var
      [cache]
      [log]
      [spool]
      [tmp]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: dir tree]

Comment: The suggested edit creates a tree which looks worse in my opinion. While it increases the distance from e.g. var to var/cache, it increases it too much and the result is rather unsightly gaps in the trunk and branches. (Not gaps in the lines drawn but gaps between items.) If the edit is approved, I will roll it back.

Comment: is there a chance to split this long tree to two halves using its own setting?

Comment: @Amir See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296692/how-do-i-split-a-forest-tree-into-two-trees-with-proper-vertical-alignment. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300413/will-prooftrees-be-able-to-typeset-this.

Comment: @Amir But note that the style itself is now supported out-of-the-box by Forest.

Comment: @Amir See edited answer above for the out-of-the-box version. If you have trouble applying the answers on splitting and you really want to do it, I'd suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 12):

Here is my take on it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\FTdir}{}
\def\FTdir(#1,#2,#3){%
  \FTfile(#1,{{\color{black!40!white}\faFolderOpen}\hspace{0.2em}#3})
  (tmp.west)++(0.8em,-0.4em)node(#2){}
  (tmp.west)++(1.5em,0)
  ++(0,-1.3em) 
}

\newcommand{\FTfile}{}
\def\FTfile(#1,#2){%
  node(tmp){}
  (#1|-tmp)++(0.6em,0)
  node(tmp)[anchor=west,black]{\tt #2}
  (#1)|-(tmp.west)
  ++(0,-1.2em) 
}

\newcommand{\FTroot}{}
\def\FTroot{tmp.west}

\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \draw[color=black!60!white]
  \FTdir(\FTroot,root,/){       % root: parent = \FTroot
    \FTdir(root,etc,etc){       % normal dir: (parentID, currentID, label)
      \FTfile(etc,passwd)       % file:       (parentID, label)
      \FTdir(etc,init,init.d){
        \FTfile(init,cron)
      }
      \FTdir(etc,apt,apt){
        \FTfile(apt,sources.list)
        \FTfile(apt,preferences)
      }
    }

    ++(0,-0.5em)                % additional space if neded

    \FTdir(root,usr,usr) {
      \FTdir(usr,bin,bin){
        \FTfile(bin,gcc)
        \FTfile(bin,g++)
      }
      \FTdir(usr,share,share){
        \FTdir(share,doc,doc){
          \FTdir(doc,gcc,gcc){
            \FTfile(gcc,...)
          }
          \FTdir(doc,gcc,gcc-7){
            \FTfile(gcc,...)
          }
        }
      }
      \FTfile(usr,...)}

    ++(0,-0.5em)

    \FTdir(root,home,home){
      \FTdir(home,user,user)
    }
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image: preview of the tree]

Comment: Very good answer. I upvote you.

Comment: fantasitic. But it is not working if long filenames are used...

Comment: how do you do the little images?

Comment: how can I change its font?

Answer (score 9):

Another example using the `tikz` `trees` library:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{every node}=[thick,anchor=west, rounded corners, font={\scriptsize\ttfamily}, inner sep=2.5pt]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=blue,fill=blue!10]
\tikzstyle{root}=[selected, fill=blue!30]

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    scale=.7,
    grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.65) and
    two children at (0.5,-0.65) and (0.5,-1.1)},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node [root] {src}
    child { node [selected] {asf}
      child { node [selected] {avr32}
        child { node [selected] {drivers}
          child { node [selected] {canif}
            child { node {canif.h}}
            child { node {canif.c}}
          }
        }
      }
    }       
    child { node at (0,-3.5) [selected] {net}
      child { node [selected] {can}
        child { node {can.h}}
        child { node {can\_mob.h}}
        child { node {can\_mob.c}}
        child { node {can\_port.h}}
        child { node {can\_port.c}}
        child { node {can\_trcv.h}}
        child { node {can\_trcv.c}}
      }
    }
    child { node at (0,-8) {\dots}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: folder structure]

Comment: This looks very nice but doesn't handle placing siblings at asf, avr32, etc. when a sibling higher up has children.