# Making TikZ nodes hyperlinkable

Tags: tikz-pgf, links

I have a TikZ tree. Now I want to make the nodes click-able directing to relevant sections in the document (or directed to URLs). Some of the content in the nodes are not text. Is it possible to turn the nodes into links, and if so, how? I would prefer the nodes themselves to be links, and not the text they contain.

**Addition**: I am not really good at it, and still learning, but here is a skeletal outline of the idea I am working on... (a graphical table of contents)

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=60mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=25mm]

\node[circle,draw,grow=down] {\textbf{COOL TOC}}
    child {node {installation}
        child {node {Linux}}
        child {node {Mac}}
        child {node {Windows}}
    }
    child {node {Get Started}
        child {node {do A}}
        child {node {do B}}
    }
    child {node {Looking Further}
        child {node {manual}}
        child {node {online}}
    }
    child[grow=up] {node {troubleshoot}
        child {node {if X happens}}
        child {node {if Y happens}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are fancier examples for example [this one](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-science-mindmap/) would make for a great TOC.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows what you've done thus far in terms of creating a `tikz` tree with some document elements.

Comment: @Werner I added the MWE.

Comment: I added a little code to complete the MWE. An MWE should provide sufficient code for a simple copy-paste-compile so that someone interested in finding a solution doesn't have to do any puzzling over what packages you're using, or type `\documentclass` etc. which gets boring. This is a nice question!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's a new TikZ style called `hyperlink node=<target>` that takes a `hypertarget` reference. It works by measuring the node it is supplied to, and then placing a new invisible node on top of that. The new node has the content `\hyperlink{<target>}{\phantom{\rule{<width of node>}{<height of node>}}`, so it has the same size as the original node, but the whole area is clickable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let     \p1 = (sourcenode.north west),
                \p2=(sourcenode.south east),
                \n1={\x2-\x1},
                \n2={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west,at=(\p1)] {\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}}
                    %xelatex needs \XeTeXLinkBox, won't create a link unless it
                    %finds text --- rules don't work without \XeTeXLinkBox.
                    %Still builds correctly with pdflatex and lualatex
        }
    }
}

\tikz \node [draw, inner sep=2ex,hyperlink node=pagetwo] {Go to Page Two};

\clearpage
\hypertarget{pagetwo}{Page Two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! I wanted to put a url link into the document so I exchanged `\hyperlink` with `\href`. This works as expected.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The output PDF has the node but it is not clickable. There were no errors in compilation, and I tried it with both Okular and Evince.

Comment: @jja: Are you using `pdflatex` for the compilation?

Comment: Ah, that was it. I was using `xelatex` and it didn't work, but I just compiled with `pdflatex` and it worked perfectly. I guess a follow-up question would be how to do this with `xelatex`, if it can be done at all...

Comment: I've tried to add this to an existing drawing and get the error message `Package pgf Error: No shape named  is known.` (note the two spaces after `named`. Any ideas?

Comment: Does not work well if the node has a `rotate` command applied to it.

Comment: I made a little improvement that maps the hyperlink area more accurate on the node by considering the option `outer sep`. I put it into an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526333/123129) below to show the difference more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from Jake's nice idea – here's some code that works fine here in a recent document using the code from [Drawing a directory listing a la the tree command in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/drawing-a-directory-listing-a-la-the-tree-command-in-tikz/34268#34268) (answer of A. Stacey) and your MWE.
It's not as fancy as your's, but maybe stylish, too.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
%------------------%
\makeatletter
\newcount\dirtree@lvl
\newcount\dirtree@plvl
\newcount\dirtree@clvl
\def\dirtree@growth{%
  \ifnum\tikznumberofcurrentchild=1\relax
  \global\advance\dirtree@plvl by 1
  \expandafter\xdef\csname dirtree@p@\the\dirtree@plvl\endcsname{\the\dirtree@lvl}
  \fi
  \global\advance\dirtree@lvl by 1\relax
  \dirtree@clvl=\dirtree@lvl
  \advance\dirtree@clvl by -\csname dirtree@p@\the\dirtree@plvl\endcsname
  \pgf@xa=0.5cm\relax % change the length to your needs
  \pgf@ya=-0.75cm\relax % change the length to your needs
  \pgf@ya=\dirtree@clvl\pgf@ya
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}}%
  \ifnum\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\tikznumberofchildren
  \global\advance\dirtree@plvl by -1
  \fi
}
\tikzset{ %definition of a new style "dirtree"
  dirtree/.style={
    growth function=\dirtree@growth,
    every node/.style={anchor=north},
    every child node/.style={anchor=west},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) |- (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)}
  }
}
\makeatother
%------------------%

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dirtree] % it's what we defined above

\node {\textbf{COOL TOC}}
    child { node {\hyperref[install]{installation} }
        child { node {\hyperref[linux]{Linux}} }
        child { node {\hyperref[mac]{Mac}} }
        child { node {\hyperref[win]{Windows}} }
    }
    child {node {\hyperref[start]{Get Started}}
        child { node {\hyperref[caseA]{do A}} }
        child { node {\hyperref[caseB]{do B}} }
    }
    child {node {\hyperref[trbl-shoot]{troubleshoot}}
        child {node {\hyperref[caseX]{if X happens}}}
        child {node {\hyperref[caseY]{if Y happens}}}
    }
    % I've put the external resources to the end:
    child {node {Looking Further}
        child { node {\href{file:manual.pdf}{manual}} }% works only, if "manual.pdf" is in
                                                       % the same directory as the compiled
                                                       % version of this document
        child { node {\href{http://website.example.com/online-resource/}{online}} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Installation}\label{install}
\subsection*{Linux}\label{linux}
Some content.

\subsection*{Mac}\label{mac}
Some content.

\subsection*{Windows}\label{win}
Some content.

\section*{Get started}\label{start}
\subsection*{First: Do A}\label{caseA}
Some content.

\subsection*{Second: Do B}\label{caseB}
 Some content.

\section*{Trouble shooting}\label{trbl-shoot}
\subsection*{If X happens:}\label{caseX}
Some content.

\subsection*{If Y happens:}\label{caseY}
 Some content.

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little improvement of [Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36111/123129).
Thanks to [frougon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73317/frougon)'s comment, different values for `outer xsep` and `outer ysep` are now correctly considered.

#### Problem

- The options `line width` and `outer sep` are not considered. Therefore, the link box is usually too large (only working case is `outer sep=0`).
- [DrBones addendum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451914/123129) does not solve this problem, because it only changes the size of the hyperlink node, but not the hyperlink area itself.

#### Solution

If `outer sep` is not set, it is half of `line width`. Therefore, we just have to use `outer sep` to solve the following cases.

I defined `\n0` and `\n1` as `outer xsep` and `outer ysep` and shifted the two points by that values to the middle of the node:

```tex
let \n0={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}},
    \n1={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}},
    \p1=([shift={(\n0, -\n1)}] sourcenode.north west),
    \p2=([shift={(-\n0, \n1)}] sourcenode.south east),
```

#### Visualization and Description

[image: result of code below]

- The node has a thick cyan border.
- The black rectangle surrounds the node anchors (`north west` and `south east`).
- The yellow rectangle is the visualization of the hyperlink area.
- The passed options are shown in the lower part of the figure.
- If yellow (hyperlink areas) and cyan (node borders) overlap, we get green, as we see in the `hyperlink dexteritas` variant.

#### Code

```tex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% NOTE: added option "test highlight" for testing (can be removed for normal usage)
\tikzset{
    test highlight/.style={draw=yellow, draw opacity=0.5},
    hyperlink Jake/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let \p1=(sourcenode.north west),
                \p2=(sourcenode.south east),
                \n1={\x2-\x1},
                \n2={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west,at=(\p1), test highlight] {\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}}
            %xelatex needs \XeTeXLinkBox, won't create a link unless it
            %finds text --- rules don't work without \XeTeXLinkBox.
            %Still builds correctly with pdflatex and lualatex
        }
    },
    hyperlink dexteritas/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let \n0={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}},
                \n1={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}},
                \p1=([shift={(\n0, -\n1)}] sourcenode.north west),
                \p2=([shift={(-\n0, \n1)}] sourcenode.south east),
                \n2={\x2-\x1},
                \n3={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=north west, at=(\p1), test highlight] {\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n2}{\n3}}}}}
            %xelatex needs \XeTeXLinkBox, won't create a link unless it
            %finds text --- rules don't work without \XeTeXLinkBox.
            %Still builds correctly with pdflatex and lualatex
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\comparison}[1][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        line width=1mm,
        node distance=5mm,
        inner sep=2mm,
        blend mode=darken,
        #1
    ]
    
    \foreach \variant [count=\i] in {Jake, dexteritas} {
        \node[text width=25mm, font=\small\ttfamily] at (0,-6) {#1};
        \node[draw=cyan, draw opacity=0.5, hyperlink \variant={test}] (a) at (0,-2*\i) {\variant};
        \draw[very thin] (a.north west) rectangle (a.south east);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\comparison
\comparison[outer sep=0mm]
\comparison[outer sep=3mm]
\comparison[outer xsep=1mm, outer ysep=4mm]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, can you please include this change in `hyperlink dexteritas`: `append after command={
            let \n0={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}},
                \n1={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}},
                \p1=([shift={(\n0, -\n1)}] sourcenode.north west),
                \p2=([shift={(-\n0, \n1)}] sourcenode.south east),
                \n2={\x2-\x1},
                \n3={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=north west, at=(\p1), draw=yellow, draw opacity=0.3] {\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n2}{\n3}}}}}}`?

Comment: Then it will work fine with e.g. `\comparison[outer xsep=3mm, outer ysep=4mm]`. (Less important: in order to visualize things better, I added `draw opacity=0.3` next to the two `draw=yellow` options.)

Comment: @frougon Thank you for pointing this out, I have adjusted the answer accordingly. Actually, it should have been obvious that if there is an `outer xsep` also an `outer ysep` exists, but I had only ever used `outer sep`, which made this not noticeable.
The idea with the transparency is also good :)

Comment: @dexteritas Thank you for this great example.  I am new to LateX. I am trying to use your example to create a button with a hyperlink (ultimately, with a URL hyperlink, but I haven't figured that out yet). I am wondering if you could tell me how to allow for rounded corners?  Currently, the highlight upon mouseover is falling outside the button border at the corners.  Please see my editable MWE at OverLeaf:  https://www.overleaf.com/5473137917hcwmhkqhyvvr       I  am wondering if there is a way to make the highlight conform to the button border?

Comment: @Steven Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "[Ask Question](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Comment: @dexteritas Thank you for  your  quick  reply!  I have posted here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687267/matching-shape-of-invisible-ghost-hyperlink-href-to-any-tikz-shape

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addendum to Jake's excellent answer and unfortunately as an answer since I can't comment yet.

I had to place many links in close proximity and for the newly created hyperref node not to protrude the original node more than it has to I had to compensate for the current line width via `inner sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth`, and set the `\XeTeXLinkMargin` to zero i.e.

```
\setlength{\XeTeXLinkMargin}{0pt}
\tikzset{
    hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let \p1= (sourcenode.north west),
                \p2= (sourcenode.south east),
                \n1={\x2-\x1},
                \n2={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,outer sep=0pt,anchor=center, at=(sourcenode.center)] {\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}}
        }
    }
}
```

Now the link is exactly as large as the (rectangular) node. When using different shapes the link will of course protrude.

Maybe this helps someone

Comment: Do you happen to  know how to  account for different shapes?  I am currently dealing with this issue as can be seen with this editable MWE on OverLeaf:   https://www.overleaf.com/5473137917hcwmhkqhyvvr