# Change on click in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

Is the following possible using the beamer class:

1. You have two images `image1.jpg` and `image2.jpg`
2. You define two "clickable" areas (a1 and a2) of your frame which you can overlay by an picture or tikzimage to simulate fancy buttons
3. If you click on a1 `image1.jpg` is shown, if you click on a2 `image2.jpg` is shown (i.e. image1 is replaced by image2).

More generally I need this for n areas and n pictures.

Here is an example. It doesn't work, since it is mainly pseudo-code and just want's to illustrate what I want. This example doesn't imply that the solution should be made of tikz or that it should be the same syntax. All what I want is what I described above.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{boolexpr}

\def\show{1}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

   \switch
   \case{\show == 1}
   \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{test1}
   \case{\show == 2}
   \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{test2}
   \otherwise
   \endswitch

   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[onclick={\show = 1}] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{Button1}};
      \node[onclick={\show = 2}] at (0,2) {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{Button2}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. You can use the `mwe` package to use the dummy images A,B,C by using `\includegraphics{example-image-a,b,c}` which loads `graphicx` package automaticaly.

Comment: Not at all. Setting up a problem is the worst part about working on an answer. Providing a basis makes it quite practical to copy/paste a code and immediately try some things on it.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind with this is the question of onward and backward navigation.  Not all PDF viewers have "back" and "forward" buttons for when you move around using hyperlinks.  So you should also have explicit "next page" and "previous page" links to get you out of your image-changing system.

Comment: Related question (at first glance): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61020/86

Comment: Can't really see what you are trying to do but will @PaulGaborit's [ocgx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx) package help? See demo file there.

Comment: @AndrewStacey by default the beamer class provides such links in the lower right corner, see for example the example slides in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/background-coloring-with-overlay-specification-in-algorithm2e-beamer-package#51590).

Answer (score 4):

Using hpesoj626's suggestion of the [`ocgx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx) package, you can do this (but it doesn't use your interface):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node at (0,0) {\begin{ocg}{Image A}{ocg1}{1}\actionsocg{}{ocg2}{ocg1}{\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}}\end{ocg}};
      \node at (0,2) {\begin{ocg}{Image B}{ocg2}{0}\actionsocg{}{ocg1}{ocg2}{\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-b}}\end{ocg}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There is also a `tikz` library provided by `ocgx` that may be of interest; it is documented in the [`ocgx` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx/ocgx-manual-en.pdf).