# Clickable areas

Tags: hyperref

Is there a more elegant way to create clickable areas in LaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={123pt,103pt},textheight=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(2.5,1)
\multiput(0,0)(0,.2){5}{\multiput(0,0)(.2,0){5}{\textcolor{white}{\nameref{sec:alpha}}}}
\put(0,0){\framebox(1,1){}}
\put(.39,.43){\textcolor{black}{$\alpha$}}
\multiput(1.5,0)(0,.186){5}{\multiput(0,0)(.186,0){5}{\textcolor{white}{\nameref{sec:Omega}}}}
\put(1.88,.378){$\Omega$}
\put(1.5,0){\framebox(1,1){}}
\end{picture}
\section*{$\alpha$\label{sec:alpha}}
\pagebreak
\section*{$\Omega$\label{sec:Omega}}
\end{document}
```

This code yields 3 pages, like these:

[image: 3 pages]

On the first page are two squares: one on the left, and one on the right. You may call these pushbuttons. When you click on the left square you go to the second page, when you click on the right square you go to the third page.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60331/89417 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36109/making-tikz-nodes-hyperlinkable could be interesting.

Comment: @Marijn: This works nicely, thanks.

Comment: Which one of the two? Then we can close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Marijn: I used this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36109/making-tikz-nodes-hyperlinkable

Answer (score 0):

Based on Marijn's suggestion a solution may go as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={123pt,103pt},textheight=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(2.5,1)
\put(0,0){\hyperlink{alpha}{\phantom{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}}
\put(0,0){\framebox(1,1){}}
\put(.39,.43){\textcolor{black}{$\alpha$}}
\put(1.5,0){\hyperlink{Omega}{\framebox(1,1){}}}
\put(1.88,.378){$\Omega$}
\end{picture}
\section*{$\alpha$}
\hypertarget{alpha}{}
\pagebreak
\section*{$\Omega$}
\hypertarget{Omega}{}
\end{document}
'''
```