# Hyperlinked nodes in TikZ mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, tikz-styles, mindmaps

I am trying to make a small mindmap such that some of the child nodes are hyperlinked. I tried to follow the advice given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36109/8863), about the new node style `hyperlink node`, but the following MWE compiles with errors.

Just to clarify the structure of the MWE, it first defines the `hyperlink node` style, which is then subsequently used in the line

```
  node[concept, hyperlink node=www.google.com] {practical}
```

Here is the MWE (which is adapted from [here](http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/computer-science-mindmap.tex)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzset{
    hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let     \p1 = (sourcenode.north west),
                \p2=(sourcenode.south east),
                \n1={\x2-\x1},
                \n2={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west,at=(\p1)] {\hyperlink{#1}{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}
        }
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Computer Science}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept, hyperlink node=www.google.com] {practical}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {algorithms} }
      child { node[concept] {data structures} }
      child { node[concept] {pro\-gramming languages} }
      child { node[concept] {software engineer\-ing} }
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {applied}
      [clockwise from=-30]
      child { node[concept] {databases} }
      child { node[concept] {WWW} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {technical} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {theoretical} };
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

Any advice on how to make mindmaps in TikZ hyperlinkable or help fixing this solution would be appreciated.

Comment: You’ll need at least the `calc` library for `let … in`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. I added `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quickest fix is to put directly inside the node the `\hyperlink`, for example:

```
node[concept] {\hyperlink{pract}{practical}}
```

This won't alter the appearance of the `concept` style.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Computer Science}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {\hyperlink{pract}{practical}}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {algorithms} }
      child { node[concept] {data structures} }
      child { node[concept] {pro\-gramming languages} }
      child { node[concept] {software engineer\-ing} }
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {applied}
      [clockwise from=-30]
      child { node[concept] {\hyperlink{datab}{databases}} }
      child { node[concept] {WWW} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {technical} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {theoretical} 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{itemize}
\item \hypertarget{pract}{Practical}: here is some description.
\item \hypertarget{datab}{Databases}: here is some description.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess this means that the whole node is not clickable?

Comment: Yes, with this approach just the text is clickable.

Comment: Ok, I will wait for a little while for someone to come along with a way to make the whole node clickable as in the `hyperlink node` style, else I will mark your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @fgnu: I've actually investigated a bit the problem, but I didn't came up with a reasonable answer. I started in chat a [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7003/hyperlinked-nodes-in-tikz-mindmap): the code there actually makes the node completely clickable, but it still generates the same errors of the question.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts. I will keep an eye on the chat threads as well. I hope you are able to find a solution. :)

Answer (score 8):

In this solution, I use `path picture` instead of `append after command`.

*(Note: the hyperlink is always a rectangular area...)*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,calc}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzset{
    hyperlink node/.style={
      postaction={
        path picture={
          \path let
          \p1 = (path picture bounding box.south west),
          \p2 = (path picture bounding box.north east),
          \p3 = (\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)
          in
          (path picture bounding box.center)
          node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=center,outer sep=0pt]
          {\hyperlink{#1}{\phantom{\rule{\x3}{\y3}}}};
        }
      },
    },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Computer Science}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept, hyperlink node=www.google.com] {practical}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {algorithms} }
      child { node[concept] {data structures} }
      child { node[concept] {pro\-gramming languages} }
      child { node[concept] {software engineer\-ing} }
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {applied}
      [clockwise from=-30]
      child { node[concept] {databases} }
      child { node[concept] {WWW} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {technical} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {theoretical} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```