# Making TikZ path into a hyperlink

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref

I'd like to know if there's a way to make an arbitrary closed path in TikZ into a hyperlink; either directly or by turning it into a node.  Here's an example of code to work with:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,filecolor=magenta]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{The Diagram}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,align=center] at (12, 0.2+.5) {Even \\ more};
\node[draw,align=center] at (12, 1.4+.5) {And \\ more1};
\node[draw,align=center] at (15, 2.8+.5) {Some \\ text };
\node[draw,align=center] at (15,1.8+.5) {More \\ text};
\draw[blue] (11,-.4+.5)--(13,-.4+.5)--(13,1.3+.5)--(16.5,1.3+.5)--(16.5,3.5+.5)--(11,3.5+.5) --(11,-.4+.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\section{this is the target}
\hypertarget{target}{}
\end{document}
```

I'd like the path in blue to become a link going to the hypertarget labeled target.  Since the path is oddly shaped, it doesn't correspond to any of the well-known node shapes in TikZ.

I've tried putting `\hyperlink{target}` around the `\draw[blue]` command, which didn't work.  I'm fine either with the blue line being the link or the region inside the blue line being the link.  I also don't care if it's still blue after the link is active; I've just colored it to make this question clearer.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I assume it would be not okay if the lower right cut-out part of the rectangle is an active link also, right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Very nice as first question: somehow [Hyperlinked nodes in TikZ mindmap](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89701/13304) is related, but this is more general.

Comment: Actually, I'd prefer that the lower right cutout portion not be part of the link.  (In my actual document, there's other stuff there which shouldn't be linked; I took it out to simplify the example.)

Comment: @LaurenPearce (If you respond to one particular comment, please include `@<username>` in your comment (as did I) so that the user gets notified.) I posted an answer that can be used for simple rectangular paths. For making the line itself hyper-active I could see a solution that uses decorations and places small boxes along the line, which would work with any arbitrary paths.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright, here is an idea for simple rectangular path that have to be split up in their convex sub-rectangles.

To get these sub-rectangles I save three coordinates for later use, the most lower-left corner, the most upper-right as well as the concave corner. There are named after their sub-rectangle (`a`, `b`) and where they lie relative to this sub-rectangle (`bl` = bottom-left, `tr` = top-right) but, of course, they can named whatever you want (and TikZ allows). The top-right coordinate of the `a` sub-rectangle is found by using `(@b@bl |- @b@tr)`, i.e. the upper-left corner of the `b` sub-rectangle.

Your coordinates on the path were very complex. I will use here (cumulative) relative coordinates but your original path can be used too, of course (see commented section).

I have filled the sub-rectangles for clarification.

The `path picture` provides a special rectangular node, the `path picture bounding box` that usually can accessed via `(path picture bounding box)` and their anchors with, say `(path picture bounding box.south west)`. Though, I will use low-level PGF macros to extract the *x*  and *y*  values of the lower-left (`south west`) and the upper-right (`north east`) corner. At the and I’ll have the dimension of the path picture in the `\pgf@?b` dimensions.

The `\pgftext` is a very low-level macro to place text somewhere in the picture.
It will placed with its upper-right corner (`right,top`) at the `north east` anchor of the path picture (`\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` still hold the values from the `north east` anchor).

The content of the `\pgftext` will be a `\vrule` of the path pictures height (`\pgf@yb`) with no depth and no width and a `\vrule` with the width of the `path picture` and no other dimensions. This essentially makes a (TeX) box the size of the path picture with no visible content.

This all is wrapped inside a two-argumenty style called `hyper`. But this is only an auxiliary style that is used by the `hyperlink` style. You can simply expand this with `\href` or whatever is needed.

The implementation in TeX/PGF makes it compatible and slightly faster.

With the help of the `calc` library you could do:

```
\path let \p{@ppbb@dim}=
         ($(path picture bounding box.north east)-(path picture bounding box.south west)$)
      in  node[inner sep=+0pt,
               outer sep=+0pt,
               anchor=north east,
               at=(path picture bounding box.north east)]
                             {#1{#2}{\rule{\x{@ppbb@dim}}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{\y{@ppbb@dim}}}};
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,filecolor=magenta]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  hyper/.style 2 args={
    path picture={%
      \pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}%
      \pgf@xb-\pgf@x
      \pgf@yb-\pgf@y
      \pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}%
      \advance\pgf@xb\pgf@x
      \advance\pgf@yb\pgf@y
      \pgftext[at={\pgfqpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}},right,top]{#1{#2}{\vrule height\pgf@yb depth0ptwidth0pt\vrule height0ptdepth0ptwidth\pgf@xb}}%
    }
  },
  hyperlink/.style={hyper=\hyperlink{#1}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{The Diagram}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,align=center] at (12, 0.2+.5) {Even \\ more};
\node[draw,align=center] at (12, 1.4+.5) {And \\ more1};
\node[draw,align=center] at (15, 2.8+.5) {Some \\ text};
\node[draw,align=center] at (15, 1.8+.5) {More \\ text};
%\draw[blue] (11,-.4+.5) coordinate (@a@bl) -- (13,-.4+.5)
%         -- (13,1.3+.5) coordinate (@b@bl) -- (16.5,1.3+.5)
%       -- (16.5,3.5+.5) coordinate (@b@tr) -- (11,3.5+.5) -| (@a@bl) -- cycle;

\draw[blue] (11,-.4+.5) coordinate (@a@bl)
         -| ++ (3  ,1.7) coordinate (@b@bl)
         -| ++ (3.5,2.2) coordinate (@b@tr) -| (@a@bl) -- cycle;
\fill[blue!20, fill opacity=.7, hyperlink=target] (@a@bl) rectangle (@b@bl |- @b@tr);
\fill[blue!40, fill opacity=.7, hyperlink=target] (@b@bl) rectangle (@b@tr);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\section{This is the target}
\hypertarget{target}{Here is the target!}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Could you maybe explain the code a little bit?  (I've got quite a few of these rectangles and I want to make sure I understand it.)  It seems that I start at the bottom left corner, and then say how much to go up and right by, right?  This defines a path and then the interior of the path gets hyperlinked.

Comment: @LaurenPearce I have updated my answer with hopefully helpful comments. It doesn’t matter how you specify the path. I have used relative coordinates because it makes it easier to follow a rectangular path. The essence is to re-use sub-rectangles for the hyperlink. How you achieve that is independent from the actual approach taken here. (I don’t think it is possible to create non-rectangular areas for a link.)