# Recognizing TiKz elements from compiled source

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, editors, viewers

I want to create (yet another) editor for TiKz pictures.  In my editor I associate to each TiKz package the possibility of creating "TiKzObjects", (e.g.) archs or nodes. From each TiKzObject I could generate a fragment of a `.tex` file that is going to be used to generate the whole output image. Such image will be used to display in a "canvas" the result of editing the TiKzObjects inside my environment. I would want that, though a canvas click, my software tells the user which TiKzObject it corresponds to. So is there any way to detect from the output image file of a .tex (pdf, png, svg) which is a correspondent object in my software environment?

Comment: Good luck with the development. The key component is the canvas, I assume that the canvas will load the rendered (by TeX system) image. PDF has some features that can help you, 1) hyperref (certain rendered object can behave as links to their original source code) 2) Inverse search (synctex), but in both cases you will have to generate some intermediate tex code. and still there is a lot of work to make your canvas able to render the PDF (and the hyperlinks!).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually first I tried to generate a svg and to [add some informations on the node](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172628/30524) `<g id="#1">…</g>` through htlatex, but actually the output didn't report such information. Moreover I even managed to find out [how to add links over edges](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169111/using-tikz-path-as-hyperref-link).


Actually now I'm trying to display pdfs and to trigger the user's click on the hyperlink.

Comment: I never managed to make individual tikz element to behave a links, not to mention links with the shape of of the object.  I would be very much interested in your progress.