# Making hyperlinked graphs with the TikZ graphdrawing package

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, tikz-graphs

[This question here garnered an interesting response on how to make TikZ node text clickable.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89701/hyperlinked-nodes-in-tikz-mindmap)

I am using the `graphdrawing` package in order to automatically set up the graph, so I am unable to use the `\hyperlink` command in the `\graph` "environment. My file at the moment looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikz [rounded corners] 
    \graph [layered layout, sibling distance=8mm, level distance=8mm]
    {
       A -> B -> C -> A
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\clearpage
\section{Target A} 
\label{sec:A}

\clearpage
\section{Target B}
\label{sec:B} 

\clearpage
\section{Target C}
\label{sec:C}

\end{document}
```

How could I set up hyperlinks to be such that if click on A in the graph, it takes me to the section titled "A" if I am using `graphdrawing`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good timing! — I just made a similar “graph of contents” for my own document. :o)

How this works: I assign labels to all sections, and use those as the names of the graph nodes. The nodes are then typeset using the command `\myref`, which outputs three hyperlinks to the given label as part of the node text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
% Use frenchlinks for nifty small caps
\usepackage[frenchlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

% Hyperlinks to:     Section #         Section name                    Page  number
%                    —————————         ————————————                    ————————————
\newcommand\myref[1]{\ref{#1}. \textbf{\nameref{#1}}\\\footnotesize p. \pageref{#1}}
%                            — —————————————————————  —————————————
%                     Period ^         Bold            Small  text

\section*{Graph of contents}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
% (Note that you don’t need both \begin{tikzpicture} and \tikz)
\graph [
  layered layout, level distance=4em, sibling distance=3em,
  nodes={
    % Draw nodes as rectangles with centered text and a bit of horizontal padding
    draw, align=center, inner xsep=0.5em,
    % Use \myref to typeset nodes using their name (viz. section label) as input
    typeset={\myref{\tikzgraphnodefullname}}
  },
] { a -> { b -> c, d } };
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{The first section}  \label{a}
\section{The second section} \label{b}
\section{The third section}  \label{c}
\section{The fourth section} \label{d}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

If you want to keep the `sec:` prefix in your section labels, you could just stick it at the beginning of the `\ref`, `\nameref`, and `\pageref` commands.

If you want the entire rectangle to be clickable, maybe take a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159700/hyperlinks-from-a-tikz-tree).

### Edit

While reading the draft of *Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications*, I noticed a good example of a [“graph of contents” on page 42](http://szeliski.org/Book/drafts/SzeliskiBook_20100903_draft.pdf#page=42):

> [image]

This kind of graph should be possible to make using the method I gave above.

---

Possibly related questions:

- [Visual table of contents using tikz mindmap or similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232550/visual-table-of-contents-using-tikz-mindmap-or-similar)
- [Creating a graphical representation of a table of contents in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258340/creating-a-graphical-representation-of-a-table-of-contents-in-tikz)

Comment: Looks cool. This could be automated.

Comment: Hm? How much more automated could you possibly make this?

Comment: It's totally doable to hijack the `\tableofcontents` command to produce that `tikzpicture` that you show here.

Comment: @1010011010 It has been a long time since you made this comment, but would you mind commenting further on automating this, perhaps with a minimal example? I would be happy to provide a bounty.

Comment: @1010011010 In particular, I am curious to know how you might end up automating how the links between the material are specified.

Comment: @user89 You can also post a new question.