# Adding hyperlinks to TikZ tree graphs gives pgf Error

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, tikz-trees, links

Slightly convoluted as I generate my TikZ graphics with Emacs `org-babel` source blocks, but I've reproduced this problem in a `.tex` file (see below).

Following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36109/making-tikz-nodes-hyperlinkable) and many related ones, I've tried to insert hyperlinks to a TikZ diagram - specifically using a graph drawing algorithm and compiling with `LuaLaTeX`. However, the `alias=sourcenode` in the `\tikzset` argument seems to create the error `Package pgf Error: No shape named 'sourcenode' is known.`

The resulting .pdf seems to be look fine, with a functioning hyperlink to the right webpage. But I'd like to remove this compilation error and/or understand how it arises. I've tried many different versions of the LaTeX style, including e.g. `\tikz [ ...]` instead of wrapping `\graph` in a `\begin{tikzpicture}[...]` block, but the error persists.

Here's my minimal(-ish) reproducible example, where I compile with

```
Running `LaTeX' on `latex-q6CtLl' with 
``lualatex --jobname=latex-q6CtLl  -file-line-error   
--synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode latex-q6CtLl.tex''
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,backgrounds,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,graphs,graphdrawing,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{trees,force} 
\pagestyle{empty}          
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    background rectangle/.style={fill=white},
    hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let     \p1 =(sourcenode.north west),
            \p2=(sourcenode.south east),
            \n1={\x2-\x1},
            \n2={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west,at=(\p1)] 
{\href{#1}{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}
        }
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={minimum height=1.5em, text depth=.2em, inner sep=0.5cm, draw=black!20, thick, fill=white, align=center}, >={Stealth[round,sep]}, rounded corners, semithick]
\graph[tree layout, grow'=-10, level distance=3cm, sibling distance=2cm,, edge quotes mid,]
{
a/"Linked node" [draw=red, hyperlink node=www.google.com],
b/"Ordinary node",
a -- b,
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the error message:

```
./latex-q6CtLl.tex:29: Package pgf Error: No shape named `sourcenode' is known.
```

Comment: Yeah, the graph drawing library saves the nodes internally (instead of drawing it), does its calculation and only then draws it. That's why `sourcenode` can't be found. You will need to either do this after the `\graph` or as a `label` (which has special consideration by the library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph drawing library saves the nodes internally (instead of drawing it), does its calculation and only then draws it.

That's why `sourcenode` can't be found.

You will need to do this this after the `\graph` command or as a `label` (which has special consideration by the library).

Here is a `label` implementation. The `parse let` key is [from my own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656319/16595).

I've removed the need for `\phantom` by using two `\rule`s with no width/height.

The border that's added to the link by `hyperref` does some weird placement things which look weird which is why I remove it via `hidelinks`. You could `draw = red` or similar to the `hyperlink node` style (not the label!) to have every hyperlinked node automatically show up with a border.

I've added a lot of keys with their default value to the label to offset the settings you did with `nodes`. It might be better to move the `nodes` key to the `\graph` command because [that's a different one](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/nodes) which won't affect the labels.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{parse let/.code={\def\tikz@cc@stop@let in{}\tikz@let@command et #1in}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}          
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  hyperlink node/.style={
    label={[%
      parse let={\p1=($(\tikzlastnode.north east)-(\tikzlastnode.south west)$)},
      minimum size=+0pt, inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt,
      path only, text depth=, text width=, text height=,
      anchor=center, sharp corners]center:%
        \hypersetup{hidelinks}\href{#1}{\rule{0pt}{\y1}\rule{\x1}{0pt}}}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  nodes={
    minimum height=1.5em, text depth=.2em, inner sep=0.5cm,
    draw=black!20, thick, fill=white, align=center},
    rounded corners, semithick]
\graph[
  tree layout, grow'=-10,
  level distance=3cm, sibling distance=2cm,
  edge quotes mid]{
    a/"Linked node" [draw=red, hyperlink node=https://www.google.com],
    b/"Ordinary node",
    a -- b,
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! Before I saw this I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159735/147085) which also seems to work for me. Thanks very much for your explanation and the link to your other answer; I will try to understand more about how and why this works but I often just forget the details as I often go a few months between using TikZ!