# Embed hyperref \Form in Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, forms

Is there any way I can embed a fillable PDF Form from hyperref's `\Form` (or anything equivalent) in a tikzpicture?

Comment: AFAIK there is no clash between hyperref and Ti*k*Z, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36111/121799). Can you please tell us what you tried?

Comment: @marmot how can I position the Textfield inside the Tikz picture; not just above or below.

Comment: Sorry, I read that on mobile and missed your link. It totally works, just injecting the code into the node name label: `\node (Y)[] {label: \TextField[width=4cm]{tfName}{}};`. I tried many more complicated things but never tried anything as simple! Thanks! Would you rewrite that as an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: @marmot I think the purpose of Jake's method is to insert a PDF annotation (e. g. a link) whose size will be dictated by the BBox of the TikZ node  into which it is inscribed. The request made here is simpler; as the size of the TikZ node simply derives from the PDF annotation size.

Comment: @AlexG Yes, that's why it is good that you (and not I) answered that question. ;-) +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, there is nothing special about `\TextField` in a `tikzpicture` environment. It can be inserted in the text argument of a TikZ node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fntSize{\f@size pt} %current font size
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] {\TextField[width=4cm, charsize=\fntSize, name=tfNameA]{label A:}};

\node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, below of=A] {\Huge\TextField[width=4cm, charsize=\fntSize, name=tfNameB]{label B:}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```