# Package for energy budget trees

Tags: trees

Is there a package that can typeset trees used for energy budgets?

[image]

The image is an extract from *Dynamic Energy and Mass Budgets in Biological Systems* by B.Kooijman which is easily identifiable as having been typeset using LaTeX. Unfortunately I have only a PDF of the book.

Comment: You could use the [dirtree](http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree) package or TikZ. Have a look at [Drawing a directory listing a la the tree command in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/drawing-a-directory-listing-a-la-the-tree-command-in-tikz).

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I am not familiar with TikZ, but the link you posted is almost what I need can you help with partial code for the down arrow in the first leaf to get me going?

Comment: dirtree is very easy to use. Try it !

Comment: @projetmbc I tried it and it works except the  I couldn't get the first level downarrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the package [pst-tree](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-tree). The following [example](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-tree/pst-tree) is taken from the [homepage of pstricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi) and shows a directory tree. You can simple adapt this. I reduced th example a litte bit to provide the code in this answer.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}% Walter Schmidt
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{geometry,url}
\usepackage{pst-tree,pst-node}
\newcounter{leaves}
\newcounter{directories}

\newenvironment{directory}[2][\linewidth]%
{%
\setcounter{leaves}{0}%
\addtocounter{directories}{1}
\edef\directoryname{D\thedirectories}
\begin{minipage}[t]{#1}% <-------- !!!
  \setlength{\parindent}{\linewidth}
  \addtolength{\parindent}{-\dirshrink\parindent}
  \parskip0pt%
  \noindent
  \Rnode[href=-\dirshrink]{\directoryname}{\parbox[t]{#1}{#2}}%
  \par
}  
{\end{minipage}}

\newcommand{\file}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{leaves}{1}%
  \edef\leaflabel{L\theleaves\directoryname}%
  \par
  \Rnode{\leaflabel}{\parbox[t]{\dirshrink\linewidth}{#1}}%
  \ncangle[angleA=270,angleB=180,armB=0,nodesep=1pt,arrows=->]
    {\directoryname}{\leaflabel}%
\par}

\newcommand{\dirshrink}{.95} 
\begin{document}
\def\url#1{#1}
\begin{directory}{\url{fontinst}}
\file{\begin{directory}{\url{doc/}}
  \file{\begin{directory}{\url{manual/}}
    \file{\url{fontinst.aux}}
    \file{\url{fontinst.log}}
    \file{\url{fontinst.pdf}}
    \file{\url{fontinst.tex}}
    \file{\url{fontinst.toc}}
    \file{\url{intro98.tex }}
    \file{\url{ltxguide.cfg}}
    \file{\url{roadmap.eps }}
  \end{directory}}
\file{\url{encspecs.zip }}
\end{directory}}
\file{\url{examples.zip }}
\file{\url{inputs.zip   }}
\file{\url{latex.zip    }}
\file{\url{README       }}
\file{\url{source.zip   }}
\file{\url{test.zip     }}
\end{directory}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course the same is possible with  the package [`tikz/pgf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or [`tikz-qtree`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-qtree).