# Changing the indentation of a Tikz tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I've drawn a directory listing style tree using code similar to that found in  [Drawing a directory listing a la the tree command in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/drawing-a-directory-listing-a-la-the-tree-command-in-tikz). I'll repeat it here for clarity

```
            \documentclass[border=10]{standalone}   
            \usepackage{tikz}

            \makeatletter
            \newcount\dirtree@lvl
            \newcount\dirtree@plvl
            \newcount\dirtree@clvl
            \def\dirtree@growth{%
              \ifnum\tikznumberofcurrentchild=1\relax
              \global\advance\dirtree@plvl by 1
              \expandafter\xdef\csname dirtree@p@\the\dirtree@plvl\endcsname{\the\dirtree@lvl}
              \fi
              \global\advance\dirtree@lvl by 1\relax
              \dirtree@clvl=\dirtree@lvl
              \advance\dirtree@clvl by -\csname dirtree@p@\the\dirtree@plvl\endcsname
              \pgf@xa=1cm\relax
              \pgf@ya=-1cm\relax
              \pgf@ya=\dirtree@clvl\pgf@ya
              \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}}%
              \ifnum\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\tikznumberofchildren
              \global\advance\dirtree@plvl by -1
              \fi
            }

            \tikzset{
              dirtree/.style={
                growth function=\dirtree@growth,
                every node/.style={anchor=north},
                every child node/.style={anchor=west},
                edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) |- (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)}
              }
            }
            \makeatother
            \begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[dirtree]
            \node {toplevel} 
                child { node {Foo}
                        child { node {foo} }
                        child { node {bar} }
                        child { node {baz} }
                }
                child { node {Bar}
                    child { node {foo} }
                    child { node {foo} }
                    child { node {foo} }
                    child { node {foo} }
                    child { node {bar} }
                    child { node {baz} }
                }
                child { node {Baz}
                    child { node {foo} }
                    child { node {bar} }
                    child { node {baz} }
                };
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{document}
```

My question is: how can I reduce the indentation of the child nodes?

Currently the anchor point comes from the south of the parent node which means the tree becomes large horizontally very quickly. I do not wish to use the parents' west as the anchor point. Ideally a point between the two would be better so the output looks like:

```
                            Root
                            |___ First Parent
                                    |__First Child
                                        |_ Grand Child
```

Rather than

```
                            Root
                            |___ First Parent
                                      |__First Child
                                               |_ Grand Child
```

Any thoughts much appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's provide a different example which shows better your problem:

```
% Assumming preamble as provided in the question
    \tikzset{
    dirtree/.style={
      growth function=\dirtree@growth,
      every node/.style={anchor=north},
      every child node/.style={anchor=west},
      edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) |- (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)}
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dirtree]
\node {toplevel} 
    child { node {Foobarish}
            child { node  {foobar} 
                    child { node {foo}} 
                  }
            child { node  {foo} 
                    child {node {foo} } 
                  }
            child { node  {bar} }
    }
    child { node {Bar}
        child { node {foo} }
        child { node {foo} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output is:

[image: Output]

This shows not only the issue you mention, but also that the vertical stems in each branch are not aligned (the branch from `Foobarish` is not aligned with the branch from `Bar`). This problem will be also solved with a proper `parent anchor` (and `growth parent anchor`) which does not depend on the size of the parent. In this case `south west` is the best choice.

The following style solves all these issues, and provides a very compact version of the tree.

```
\tikzset{
  dirtree/.style={
    growth function=\dirtree@growth,
    growth parent anchor=south west,
    parent anchor=south west,
    every child node/.style={anchor=west},
    edge from parent path={([xshift=2ex] \tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) 
                           |- (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)}
  }
}
```

[image: Final result]

Thanks to Andrew Stacey and Jake for their useful comments about the need to set also `growth parent anchor` (their comments below refer to an early version of this answer).

Comment: But the children of `Foobarish` are still not aligned with the children of `Bar` so this only solves the part of the problem relating to drawing the paths.  I think that to align all the children and grandchildren one would need to adjust things a bit deeper.  Trees are drawn by transforming first to the centre of the parent node.  This is what would need changing, I think.

Comment: @Jake Just come to the same conclusion ...

Comment: @AndrewStacey and Jake, thank you for pointing at that issue and providing a solution. I updated the answer.

Comment: @JLDiaz: As you did change the anchor usage: Actually, I had added these to Andrew’s answer, and I did it only by try & error. Your new approach breaks in my real case (that also was the reason for contributing to Andrew’s answer). My first try here was to add an x-shift also to `every child node/.style`, this would work, but it is really complicated to fiddle out good values for both `xshift`s, then. I at last decided to change all parent anchors to `south`. In my case now the vertical lines are still almost aligned, because the nodes are almost the same length.

Comment: @JLDiaz:  The best, I think, would be something like `anchor=1em right of south west`. BTW please add a remark in the code, that the value of `xshift` can be and perhaps should be adjusted to one’s own needs.