# nodes structure like file system

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees

I would like to draw a picture that reflects some file structure. Below code works almost as expected. I need to adjust the connections between nodes so they don't start from the center of the bottom of the parent node but from near the left bottom corner.

How can I do this?

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}                           % super package for complex and awesome drawing

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=1pt]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=cyan,fill=cyan!30]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},   
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {MainFolder-\{version\}}
    child { node [label={[xshift=6.0cm, yshift=-0.58cm, color=gray] Documentation for developers}] {References and Documentation/}
        child { node [draw=none] {main.html} }
        child { node {reference/}
            child { node [draw=none] {...}}
        }
        child [missing] {}
    }
    child [missing] {}
    child [missing] {}
    child [missing] {}
    child { node {release/}
        child { node [draw=none] {libAwesome.a} }
        child { node [draw=none] {libAwesome.dylib} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[] % resets borders of tables
\tikzstyle{selected}=[] % resets selected

\end{document}
```

### Ouput:

[image]

### Ideal:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Changing the indentation of a TikZ tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89129/changing-the-indentation-of-a-tikz-tree) might help, that's a remarkably similar problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to set

- the start of the `edge from parent path`

  - `parent anchor=south west` (is going to be saved in `\tikzparentanchor`)
  - `+ .4cm` to the right
  - `child anchor` (`\tikzchildanchor`) need not to be set as the `|-` path operator takes care of that (the default `.center` anchor has the same *y* value as `.west`);
- and the start of the growth function (`grow via three points`)

  - `growth parent anchor=west`
- and the end of the growth function

  - `every child node/.style={anchor=west}`

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        draw=black,
        thick,
        anchor=west,
        inner sep=2pt,
        minimum size=1pt,
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    grow via three points={
        one child at (0.8,-0.7) and two children at (0.8,-0.7) and (0.8,-1.4)
    },
    edge from parent path={
        ($(\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor)+(.4cm,0pt)$) |- (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)
    },
    growth parent anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south west,% = \tikzparentanchor
%   child anchor=west,%        = \tikzchildanchor
%   every child node/.style={anchor=west}% already in "every node"
  ]
  \node {MainFolder-\{version\}}
    child { node [label={[xshift=6.0cm, yshift=-0.58cm, color=gray] Documentation for developers}] {References and Documentation/}
        child { node [draw=none] {main.html} }
        child { node {reference/}
            child { node [draw=none] {\ldots}}
        }
        child [missing] {}
    }
    child [missing] {}
    child [missing] {}
    child [missing] {}
    child { node {release/}
        child { node [draw=none] {libAwesome.a} }
        child { node [draw=none] {libAwesome.dylib} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]