# Trees in latex : 2 nodes on the same line with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm following the tutorial/MWE provided at this link : http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/filesystem-tree/

I would like to have to nodes at the same line, for example :

```
[MAIN]
|__________[UNDERMAIN1]____[PROPERTY1.1]_____[PROPERTY1.2]
|__________[UNDERMAIN2]____[PROPERTY2]
           |____________[UNDERUNDERMAIN2]_______[PROPERTY3]
```

So far I only found the way having the [properties] on below [undermain], but not at the same line.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It looks as if you have different kinds of children: the ones that go below right their parent, and then the ones that go only to the right. I’d simply add them manually after the tree has been built. By the way, have you seen, that this example has been improved by TeX.sx users. See [Drawing a directory listing a la the tree command in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23647) and [Changing the indentation of a Tikz tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89129). These changes don’t effect placement of “properties” but a more automatic way how children are placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest to do this is to add the property nodes later to a named node.

The solution consists of the keys

- `property direction`,
- **`properties`**,

and the styles

- `every property` and
- `every property edge`.

After the tree has been built, the `properties` are used via `late options`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  property direction/.initial=mid right,
  properties/.style={
    append after command={
      \pgfextra\let\qrr@tikzlastnode\tikzlastnode\endpgfextra
      \foreach \pgf@temp[count=\qrr@tikz@fig@prop from 0] in {#1} {
        \pgfextra
          \ifnum\qrr@tikz@fig@prop=0
            \let\qrr@tikz@fig@suffix\pgfutil@empty
          \else
            \edef\qrr@tikz@fig@suffix{-\number\numexpr\qrr@tikz@fig@prop-1\relax}%
          \fi
        \endpgfextra
        node [
          every property/.try,
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/property direction}=of \qrr@tikzlastnode\qrr@tikz@fig@suffix,
          name=\qrr@tikzlastnode-\qrr@tikz@fig@prop] {\pgf@temp}
        edge[every property edge/.try] (\qrr@tikzlastnode\qrr@tikz@fig@suffix)
      }
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  every property/.style={
    thin,
    node distance=.25cm,
  },
  every property edge/.style={densely dotted,-}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={draw=black,thick,anchor=west,text height=\heightof{A}, text depth=+0pt},
  selected/.style={draw=red,fill=red!30},
  optional/.style={dashed,fill=gray!50},
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
]
  \node (texmf) {texmf}
    child { node (doc) {doc} }
    child { node {fonts} }
    child { node {source}}
    child { node [selected] {tex}
      child { node {generic}}
      child { node [optional] {latex}}
      child { node {plain}}
    }
    child [missing] {}
    child [missing] {}
    child [missing] {}
    child {node {texdoc}};

    \path [late options={name=doc,properties={a,b,c}}];

    \path [late options={name=texmf-1,properties={d,e,f}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]