# How to use macros in command \dirtree of package dirtree?

Tags: expansion, dirtree

I want to print a tree structure and started using the package dirtree (v0.32,
see [Making a (simple) directory tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree)). Following calls work smooth:

```
\dirtree{.1 root. .2 child1. .2 child2. .3 childofchild2. }

\def\mytree{{.1 root. .2 child1. .2 child2. .3 childofchild2. }}
\expandafter\dirtree\mytree{}
```

`\dirtree` will draw a tree representation like

```
root
 |-- child1
 |-- child2
      |-- child of child2
```

But a problem arises if the generation of the tree data is using some more complex macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}
% edited to remove the use of counters
%\newcounter{qtreedepth}
%\def\nodeC#1{\addtocounter{qtreedepth}{1}#1\addtocounter{qtreedepth}{-1}}
%\renewcommand{\item}[1]{.\arabic{qtreedepth} #1. }
\def\nodeC#1{{#1}}
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{.1 #1. }

\begin{document}
\nodeC{\myitem{root}\nodeC{\myitem{child}}}

\expandafter\dirtree{\nodeC{\myitem{root}\nodeC{\myitem{child}}}}
\end{document}
```

The error message:

```
! Use of \next doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \myitem 
                   {root}\nodeC {\myitem {child}}
l.11 ...nodeC{\myitem{root}\nodeC{\myitem{child}}}
```

Is there something wrong with the expansion? Is the usage of `\expandafter` correct? Any idea what is wrong?

(Meanwhile I discovered the page on tree drawing in TikZ, 
[Drawing a directory listing a la the tree command in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/drawing-a-directory-listing-a-la-the-tree-command-in-tikz). Worth trying, but on the other I'd like to know the reason why above does not work...)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not a good idea to redefine `\item`, to begin with. Can you give a graphical (approximate) representation of what you want to do?

Comment: A quick read of the `dirtree` docs makes me suspect that `\dirtree` requires a fully-expanded argument. So `\dirtree{.1 root.}` is fine (that's what your `\expandafter` will generate), but something with `\stepcounter` can never work as it's not expandable.

Comment: @egreg The `\item` is a leftover because I want to use lists, thus, the redefinition. Reading that environments are not expandable I avoided lists for `\dirtree`.

The graphical output should have a structure like

`root
 |- child1
     |- child of child1`

The input structure should use environments.

`\begin{nodeC}
\item{root}
\begin{nodeC}
\item{child1}
\begin{nodeC}\item{child of child1}\end{nodeC}
\end{nodeC}
\end{nodeC}`

The closest solution would be to change to TikZ package and modify the code of [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23647) of Tom Bombadil.

Comment: @Joseph Wright
Though I am not that familiar with Tex programming yet, I had the same impression that `\dirtree` just wants "plain text" (fully expanded macros).

Now I removed all the counter stuff but I get still the same error... Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to implement the syntax you prefer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}

\newcounter{nodeCdepth}
\newenvironment{nodeC}
  {\ifnum\value{nodeCdepth}=0
     \gdef\listfordirtree{}%
     \let\item\nodeCitem
    \fi
    \stepcounter{nodeCdepth}}
  {\addtocounter{nodeCdepth}{-1}%
   \ifnum\value{nodeCdepth}=0
     \expandafter\dirtree\expandafter{\listfordirtree}%
   \fi}
\newcommand{\nodeCitem}[1]{%
  \xdef\listfordirtree{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\listfordirtree}%
    .\thenodeCdepth\space\unexpanded{#1}. }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{nodeC}
  \item{root}
  \begin{nodeC}
    \item{bin}
    \begin{nodeC}
      \item{home}
    \end{nodeC}
    \item{xu}
  \end{nodeC}
\end{nodeC}

\dirtree{.1 root.  .2 bin.  .3 home.  .2 xu. }
\end{document}
```

Just for comparison I've added the usual `dirtree` syntax.

[image]

I maintain the depth in the `nodeCdepth` counter; when it's zero, either we are starting (at `\begin{nodeC}`) and a container macro is initialized to empty or we are ending (at `\end{nodeC}`) and the container macro is delivered to `\dirtree` for processing the list of nodes. When the counter has a value greater than zero, `\item` will add its argument to the container macro, surrounded by the tokens required by the syntax of `\dirtree`.

Comment: Many thks! - So the creation of a container (`\listfordirtree`) to store the argument
avoids the problem with non-expandable counter manipulations (\stepcounter etc.). I found that `\item` without braces would be easier to use (e.g. `\item root`
instead of `\item{root}`). But probably this goes far beyond the scope of this question and I will ask a separate question. Anyway, this solution works fine!