# Fail to define command to automate construction of dirtree complex item

Tags: macros, dirtree

I'm able to generate a complex tree item in LaTeX with dirtree manually (see MWE below). In order to avoid the recurrent repetition of code, I tried to set the declaration of each tree item within a LaTeX command. However, I get the error `! Use of \next doesn't match its definition.`

Here the expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Here the minimum working example (MWE) without the use of command:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\thisfloatsetup{%
objectset=raggedright,
}
\begin{document}
\dirtree{%
    .1 node1 \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}
    { }
    \end{minipage} \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5cm}
    long comment multiline line number 1
    \end{minipage}.
    .2 node2 \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}
    type 0
    \end{minipage} \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5cm}
    long comment multiline line number 2
    \end{minipage}.
    .3 leaf1 \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}
    type 1
    \end{minipage} \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5cm}
    long comment multiline line number 3
    \end{minipage}.
    .3 leaf2 \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}
    type 1
    \end{minipage} \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5cm}
    long comment multiline line number 4
    \end{minipage}.
    .2 node3 \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}
    type 0
    \end{minipage} \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5cm}
    very very very very long comment multiline line number 5
    \end{minipage}.
    .3 leaf3 \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}
    type 2
    \end{minipage} \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5cm}
    long comment multiline line number 6
    \end{minipage}.
    .3 leaf4 \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}
    {}
    \end{minipage} \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5cm}
    no type specified
    \end{minipage}.
}
\end{document}
```

Here the attempt of defining a command `\treedef` to avoid the repetition of redundant code

```
\documentclass[8pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% #1: Level
% #2: Name
% #3: Type
% #4: Comment
\newcommand{\treedef}[4]{
    .{#1} {#2} \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}
    {#3}
    \end{minipage} \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5cm}
    {#4}
    \end{minipage}.
}

\thisfloatsetup{%
objectset=raggedright,
}
\begin{document}
\dirtree{%
    \treedef{1}{node1}{}{long comment multiline line number 1}
    \treedef{2}{node2}{type 0}{long comment multiline line number 2}
    \treedef{3}{leaf1}{type 1}{long comment multiline line number 3}
    \treedef{3}{leaf2}{type 1}{long comment multiline line number 4}
    \treedef{2}{node3}{type 0}{very very very very long comment multiline line number 5}
    \treedef{3}{leaf3}{type 2}{long comment multiline line number 6}
    \treedef{3}{leaf4}{}{no type specified}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[8pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% #1: Level
% #2: Name
% #3: Type
% #4: Comment

\newcommand{\treedef}[4]{%
    \appto\dirtreecode{%  ← must have no space at the beginning
    .#1 #2 \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}
    #3
    \end{minipage} \hfill \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5cm}
    #4
    \end{minipage}. % ← must have a space here
    }%
}

\thisfloatsetup{%
objectset=raggedright,
}

\begin{document}

\def\dirtreecode{}
\treedef{1}{node1}{}{long comment multiline line number 1}
\treedef{2}{node2}{type 0}{long comment multiline line number 2}
\treedef{3}{leaf1}{type 1}{long comment multiline line number 3}
\treedef{3}{leaf2}{type 1}{long comment multiline line number 4}
\treedef{2}{node3}{type 0}{very very very very long comment multiline line number 5}
\treedef{3}{leaf3}{type 2}{long comment multiline line number 6}
\treedef{3}{leaf4}{}{no type specified}
%\show\dirtreecode  % execute this if you want to see what is going to be put inside \dirtree{...}
\expandafter\dirtree\expandafter{\dirtreecode}

\end{document}
```

I ignore the "underfull hbox" error messages, since they aren't the main issue here.

Basically the code builds the whole of the "body" using `\appto`, before passing it to `\dirtree` using `\expandafter`.

Comment: For learning LaTeX programming: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668 ■ somewhat related question: [expansion - How to use macros in command \dirtree of package dirtree?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93965) ■ special case 3 of my answer in [verbatim - Why can't I use <some macro> inside the argument of <some other macro>? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645995) -- where the `\dirtree` macro does not expand things inside it, which makes the user-defined macro not expanded. ■ Be careful with `%` and spaces: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. FYI, I understood that there was an issue with "expansion". However, I was not aware of your answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645995 which makes more clear for me the exact reason of the issue. I will definitely study the solution to understand how it works.