# Spacing elements in forest environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, forest

I need to typeset a directory tree, and I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249215/92789) an appropriate solution using `forest` package. After a slight modification (the squares on the paths, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270761/92789)), I got this:

[image: what I got]

Unfortunately, as you can see, the spacing between elements is far from perfect. Take, for example, the vertical distance between `text 5.1` and `text 6`, and that between `text 6` and `text 5.2`: they are (significantly and dreadfully) different, which I don't accept.

Is there a way to solve this problem, that is, to have all elements spaced correctly?

---

The following is the code for the tree in the picture:

```
\begin{forest} dir tree,
for tree = {font=\ttfamily}
[text 1
    [text 2
        [text 3
            [text 4
                [text 5.1
                    [text 6]
                ][text 5.2
]]]]]
\end{forest}
```

And these are `forest` settings:

```
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  dir tree/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south west,
      child anchor=west,
      anchor=mid west,
      inner ysep=0pt,
      grow'=0,
      align=left,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) ++(1em,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      if n children=0{}{
        delay={
          prepend={[,phantom, calign with current]}
        }
      },
      fit=band,
      before computing xy={
        l=2em
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the distance is really similar, but not identical to the decimal?

Comment: I'm sorry, @Alenanno, I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: I'm measuring the distance between the three elements, and one distance is 22.34, the other is 22.14. So a 0.2 difference in distance.

Comment: @Alenanno Unfortunately in my diagram the pieces of text are longer, so the issue with the vertical spacing is more visible...

Comment: Please post complete examples i.e. the complete code required to reproduce a problem, when asking questions as it makes things much easier for helpers and anybody interested in the topic of the question, even if the ideas are new to them.

Comment: @cfr I'm sorry, I thought that the code I posted was sufficient. Anyway, your answer perfectly solved my problem. I'll need to study it a bit, to better understand the changes that you made, but it works. So thanks!

Comment: It is better if you post something which  can be copy-paste-compiled. Especially for people less familiar with the packages etc. (Also, it is just easier generally.) If you want to understand it, two things may help. One is to add `draw` to the nodes of your original tree. The other is to add `x, draw` in place of `, phantom`. It makes it easier to see what is happening. (At least, that's what I did.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

[image: modified dir tree]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  dir node/.style={
    parent anchor=south west,
    child anchor=west,
    anchor=west,
    inner ysep=0pt,
    align=left,
  },
  dir tree/.style={
    for tree={
      grow'=0,
      dir node,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) ++(1em,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      if n children=0{}{
        delay={
          prepend={[text 1, dir node, phantom, calign with current]}
        }
      },
      fit=band,
      before computing xy={
        l=2em,
      }
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  dir tree,
  for tree = {
    font=\ttfamily
  }
  [text 1
    [text 2
      [text 3
        [text 4
          [text 5.1
            [text 6]
          ]
          [text 5.2
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```