# Is it possible to create a list with lines connecting elements in the same level?

Tags: lists, enumerate, trees

I'm trying to replicate the following in LaTex:

[image: a nested list with lines connecting it]

Is there a package that can do it, or a simple way to do it? I've searched around, but couldn't find anything the made exactly this (probably due to wrong keywords).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/drawing-a-directory-listing-a-la-the-tree-command-in-tikz

Answer (score 4):

`dirtree` is a package specifically designed for these kinds of diagrams. However, I'd probably use Forest's `edge` library's (misleadingly named) `folder` style.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    folder,
    grow'=0,
    align=left,
    % Sašo: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35178162#35178162
    child anchor=mid west,
  },
  [Things it is time to speak of \dots
    [Shoes
      [An invention designed to mitigate the\\disadvantages suffered by the wealthy as a\\result of inflicting roads on the poor.]
    ]
    [Ships
      [Occasionally to be found in bottles.]
    ]
    [Sealing was
      [Not to be confused with ceiling wax.]
    ]
    [Cabbages
      [{Plant of historical importance for its role\\in the production of a soup, ostensibly\\given from charity, but actually inflicted\\as punishment for misfortune.}]
    ]
    [Kings
      [Hereditary obsolescence.]
    ]
    [Why the sea is boiling hot
      [\emph{Non sequitur}.]
    ]
    [Whether pigs have wings
      [Falsehood.
        [\emph{A posteriori.}]
        [Contingent.]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Carroll will be turning in his grave, no doubt]

Answer (score 3):

This works:  (minor adaptation of [texample](http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/filesystem-tree.tex))

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{comment}
:Title: Filesystem tree
:Tags: Trees; Styles
:Author: Frantisek Burian
:Slug: filesystem-tree
\end{comment}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
%\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
%\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
%\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (1.0,-0.7) and
  two children at (1.0,-0.7) and (1.0,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {texmf}
    child { node {doc}}     
    child { node {fonts}}
    child { node {source}}
    child { node {tex}
      child { node {generic}}
      child { node {latex}}
      child { node {plain}}
    }
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child { node {texdoc}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not use `minimal` for examples. It is not at all suitable.

Comment: Just copied the original with minor adjustments, as mentioned.  Hadn't even noticed that.