# Is there a standard way to represent the file tree in a rather elaborate code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, files

I've got a program which is split into some files located in two main folders, *src* and *include*, with the header *.h* files in the *include* folder while *.cpp* and *.cu* files in the other. Here is a little drawing for the whole routine

[image]

**Note#1** this is not exactly what I want to achieve but it may be a starting point.

**Note#2** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885937/whats-the-technical-definition-for-routine) you can find the meaning of the word routine, but here I mean just a complex application split into multiple files.

Is there a **standard way to represent the tree of the files which a program is composed of?** I mean the file tree, along with the folders tree. I'm looking for some solution to even add *some* of the relations within the files with some arrows. I'd like to use **tikz** if possible.

Right now this is my poor, far-to-be-optimized tikz image I realized:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth',
    pil/.style={
           ->,
           thick,
           shorten <=2pt,
           shorten >=2pt,},
    gpufile/.style={
            rectangle,
            rounded corners,
            draw=red, very thick,
            minimum height=2em,
            minimum width=8em,
            text centered
            },
    cpufile/.style={
            rectangle,
            rounded corners,
            draw=black, thick,
            minimum height=2em,
            text centered
            },
    header/.style={
            rectangle,
            draw=gray, thin,
            minimum height=2em,
            minimum width=5em,
            text centered
            },
    folder/.style={
            rectangle,
            draw=yellow, thin,
            minimum height=3em,
            minimum width=5em,
            text centered
            }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, auto,]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[-latex,thick]
\node[
        folder,
        xshift=-2cm] (src) {src};
\node[
        cpufile, 
        right of=src,
        xshift=40pt] (main) {\texttt{main.cpp}};
\node[
        gpufile, 
        right of=main,
        xshift=40pt,
        yshift=0pt] (trbdf2) {\texttt{tr-bdf2.cu}}
    ;
\node[
        gpufile,
        right of=trbdf2,
        xshift=40pt,
        yshift=0cm
        ] (jacobian) {\texttt{jacobian.cu}};
\node[  
        gpufile,
        right of=jacobian,
        xshift=60pt
        ] (inversion) {\texttt{matrix\_inversion.cu}};
\node[
        gpufile,
        right of=inversion,
        xshift=60pt] (tr) {\texttt{newton\char`_tr.cu}};
\node[
        gpufile,
        right of=tr,
        xshift=60pt] (bdf2) {\texttt{newton\char`_bdf2.cu}};
\node[
        folder,
        below of=src,
        yshift=-1cm] (include) {include};
\node[
        header,
        right of=include,
        xshift=40pt] (libs) {\texttt{libs.h}};
\node[
        header,
        right of=libs,
        xshift=40pt] (constants) {\texttt{constants.h}};
\node[
        header,
        right of=constants,
        xshift=40pt] (fdefs) {\texttt{functions\char`_defs.h}};
\node[
        header,
        right of=fdefs,
        xshift=40pt] (defs) {\texttt{defs.h}};
\node[
        header,
        right of=defs,
        xshift=40pt] (linsolver) {\texttt{linear\char`_solver.h}};
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I need to highlight *.cu* files in the project, they have a different meaning from the clasic *.cpp* files.

While sliding through the [tikz library samples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) the closest I found to what I mean is [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/filesystem-tree/), which is recommended just for a filesystem directory tree though.

Comment: Your code is not compileable at this moment. I added the missing code ans a picture of the output.

Comment: Thank you @Dr. Manuel Kuehner, I updated the picture as well

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What do you mean by a coding *routine* which is composed of *folders*? These concepts don't really fit well together for me. Maybe you can give an example to show what you want to acchieve (maybe draw it quickly by hand)?

Comment: @pschulz Done! Not exactly what I want to achieve but I hope it explains

Comment: I'm sorry, i still don't understand what you want to acchieve. For me, a routine is something you *do*. Now, in this context the term folders makes no sense. Language aside, i still don't get it. Here's my guess: you want to show the process how the program is build (using `make`). During this, you want to highlight the current used (and included) files. If this is the case, i would use a different approach. Drop the notion of two different folders, just show that files are included. But then, i don't know what a *standard representation* would be, and i feel that there is none.

Comment: @pschulz Edited. Hope it explains my question better now: I just wanted to know some solution to represent the file tree that composes my program; in particular if there is some standard way to do it. But then yep, showing the `Makefile` should be useful and I'll consider it

Comment: I'm still confused.  Do you want (for example) the output of `ls -r` (possibly differently formatted)?  This is something like your image at the end that lists the files and the directories that contain them.  What's wrong with that?  Or do you want to print the contents of your `Makefile`?  Or do you want one of those options plus some arrows connecting some of the files?  And do you want this to happen automatically, or are you willing to type in the files and the relations?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't represent the directory tree in the standard way, adding arrows or whatever if necessary. I assume that's not it, because (1) that seems very obvious and simple-minded and (2) there are a lot of examples of this already, so it would hardly be a mystery how to do it. (`dirtree` doesn't support Ti*k*Z, but Forest's `folder` style certainly does.)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/drawing-a-directory-listing-a-la-the-tree-command-in-tikz¸ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328886/making-a-directory-tree-of-folders-and-files, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351196/is-it-possible-to-create-a-list-with-lines-connecting-elements-in-the-same-level and many more ..., A bit different:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46476/tikz-tree-edge-alignment-in-horizontal-org-chart/271364#271364, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339876/growing-trees-with-forest-package and many more ....

Comment: @cfr: I guess, OP isn't aware of the standard way, hence the question *"Is there a standard way to ..."*.