wrapfig2: unwanted vertical spacing with `enumerate` env
Is it possible to fix the code given below to avoid extra vertical spaces with enumerate env? See the two pictures just after.





Here is the code used.
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[french]{babel, varioref}
\frenchsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}

\usepackage{wrapfig2}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424061/6880

\newcommand{\FTdirO}{}
\def\FTdirO(#1,#2,#3){%
  \FTfile(#1,{\color{blue!40!black}\faFolderOpen\hspace{-.35pt}}{\hspace{0.2em}#3})
  (tmp.west)++(0.8em,-0.4em)node(#2){}
  (tmp.west)++(1.5em,0)
  ++(0,-1.3em) 
}

\newcommand{\FTdirC}{}
\def\FTdirC(#1,#2,#3){%
  \FTfile(#1,{\color{blue!40!black}\faFolder\hspace{.75pt}}{\hspace{0.2em}#3})
  (tmp.west)++(0.8em,-0.4em)node(#2){}
  (tmp.west)++(1.5em,0)
  ++(0,-1.3em) 
}

\newcommand{\FTfile}{}
\def\FTfile(#1,#2){%
  node(tmp){}
  (#1|-tmp)++(0.6em,0)
  node(tmp)[anchor=west,black]{\tt #2}
  (#1)|-(tmp.west)
  ++(0,-1.2em) 
}

\newcommand{\FTroot}{}
\def\FTroot{tmp.west}

\newcommand\contribtranslatedirtree{
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw[color=black, thick]
% en        : parent = \FTroot
% normal dir: (parentID, currentID, label)
% file      :       (parentID, label)
      \FTdirO(\FTroot,root,translate){
        \FTdirC(root,changes,changes){
        }
        \FTdirO(root,en,en) {    
          \FTdirC(en,api,api) {
          } 
          \FTdirC(en,doc,doc) {
          } 
        } 
        \FTdirC(root,fr,fr){
        }
        \FTdirC(root,status,status){
          \FTdirO(status,en,en) {
            \FTfile(en,api.yaml)
            \FTfile(en,manual.yaml)
          } 
          \FTdirC(status,fr,fr){
          }
        }
        \FTfile(root,README.md)
        \FTfile(root,LICENSE.txt)
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}
    \contribtranslatedirtree\
    \caption{Vue simplifiée du dossier des traductions}
    \label{tdoc-contrib-tranlsate-dir}
\end{wrapfigure}{}

Bla, bla

\section{Blo, blo}
    
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \blindtext
    \item \blindtext
    \item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

