# utf8 characters

Tags: fonts, symbols, unicode, characters, input-encodings

I would like to include the output of the `npm list` command in a latex verbatim block:

```
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ npm install d3
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ npm list
/home/jeroen/Desktop
└─┬ d3@2.10.3
  ├─┬ jsdom@0.2.14
  │ ├─┬ contextify@0.1.3
  │ │ └── bindings@1.0.0
  │ ├── cssom@0.2.5
  │ ├── htmlparser@1.7.6
  │ └─┬ request@2.12.0
  │   ├─┬ form-data@0.0.3
  │   │ ├── async@0.1.9
  │   │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.3
  │   │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
  │   └── mime@1.2.7
  └── sizzle@1.1.0
```

However the funny little tree characters are non ascii. I tried saving the file as UTF8 and adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to my premable. However, it gives me the errors:

```
 -Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:â not set up for use with LaTeX
```

Is there any way I can use these characters?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree and http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree .

Comment: If you're dead set on including the actual raw text, you could compile with LuaTeX or XeLaTeX using a font that contains the relevant characters as the monospaced font.

Comment: If you don't want to use a unicode TeX, you more or less need to design an input encoding for the respective code page which can be setup to be used with the `utf8` package. It's not that hard, but you need to decide whether it's worth the trouble.

Comment: You can do `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{252C}{...}` with `...` any valid LaTeX code that draws ┬ (with `picture` mode or getting the glyph from a font), and the same for the other needed glyphs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example, package [`pmboxdraw`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pmboxdraw.pdf) provides the symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
/home/jeroen/Desktop
└─┬ d3@2.10.3
  ├─┬ jsdom@0.2.14
  │ ├─┬ contextify@0.1.3
  │ │ └── bindings@1.0.0
  │ ├── cssom@0.2.5
  │ ├── htmlparser@1.7.6
  │ └─┬ request@2.12.0
  │   ├─┬ form-data@0.0.3
  │   │ ├── async@0.1.9
  │   │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.3
  │   │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
  │   └── mime@1.2.7
  └── sizzle@1.1.0
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Perfect. Is there a way of finding out which packages contain certain characters?

Comment: [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) can help.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a plain LaTeX solution (*not* using tikz).  You need to set up the missing unicode chars.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\makeatletter
\verbatim@font
\newsavebox\v@sp
\sbox{\v@sp}{\ }
\newlength{\v@spwd}
\setlength{\v@spwd}{\wd\v@sp}
\newunicodechar{└}{\mbox{\kern0.5\v@spwd\vrule height 2ex depth -1ex width 0.2ex\kern-0.2ex\rule[1ex]{0.5\v@spwd}{0.2ex}}}
\newunicodechar{─}{\rule[1ex]{1\v@spwd}{0.2ex}}
\newunicodechar{┬}{\rule[1ex]{0.5\v@spwd}{0.2ex}\vrule height 1ex
depth 0.5ex width0.2ex\kern-0.2ex\rule[1ex]{0.5\v@spwd}{0.2ex}}
\newunicodechar{├}{\mbox{\kern0.5\v@spwd\vrule height 2ex depth 0.5ex width 0.2ex\kern-0.2ex\rule[1ex]{0.5\v@spwd}{0.2ex}}}
\newunicodechar{│}{\mbox{\kern0.5\v@spwd\vrule height 2ex depth 0.5ex width
0.2ex\kern-0.2ex \kern0.5\v@spwd}}
\makeatother
\normalfont

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ npm install d3
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ npm list
/home/jeroen/Desktop
└─┬ d3@2.10.3
  ├─┬ jsdom@0.2.14
  │ ├─┬ contextify@0.1.3
  │ │ └── bindings@1.0.0
  │ ├── cssom@0.2.5
  │ ├── htmlparser@1.7.6
  │ └─┬ request@2.12.0
  │   ├─┬ form-data@0.0.3
  │   │ ├── async@0.1.9
  │   │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.3
  │   │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
  │   └── mime@1.2.7
  └── sizzle@1.1.0
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

The `newunicodechar` package gives a simple way to access the necessary code points.

In the code all symbols are made with vertical and horizontal rules.  We need to get the width of a space character in the verbatim font and make our symbols that width to get the correct alignment in the output.  The width is stored in `\v@spwd` and used for subsequent horizontal measurements.  (I kill the width of the vertial rules by backing up by their width, to make this easier.)  Also symbols starting with some space are enclosed in an box, to prevent this space disappearing at the beginning of each line.

One could adjust the height/depth of the veritcal rules to make them join up between lines, but it is probably not the style you want to see.

Comment: +1 (and not only for the use of `newunicodechar`). :)

Comment: +1 you could replace `\mbox` by `\mbox{}\smash` which then makes it easier to enlarge the vertical rules without upsetting the interline spacings.