# Creating appealing directory trees - alternative to dirtree

Tags: diagrams, trees

I already found a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree) and thus know about the [dirtree](http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree) package. However, the result does not really look nice.

Also I'd like to put the tree in a figure environment and get it centered. This just does not work since only the text is centered, not the tree structure

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \dirtree{%
    .1 spam.
    .2 ham.
    .2 eggs.
    .3 more spam.
    .3 dead parrots.
  }
  \caption[Directory Structure]{This is an example directory structure.}
  \label{fig:dir}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a better way to create file system visualizations?

Comment: You will have to be more specific about what you would like the result to look like.

Comment: To me it just looks ugly. I know that's subjective. It also seems that it does not behave well in a figure environment, I'll add that to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tikz  trees are more complex but allow a fine tuning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=gray, very thick,anchor=west]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and %
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},%
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)%
  |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
\node {root}
    child { node {spam}}     
    child { node {ham}}
    child { node {eggs}
       child {node {more spam} }
      child { node {dead parrots}}}
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child { node {peanuts}};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Is it possible to place a `tikzpicture` in a figure environment and center it? (I can't just try it on my own right now...)

Comment: @Scolytus. Yes. No problem `:-)`.

Comment: I think you should adjust the height to be the same for every directory.