# Draw directory tree using folder icons

Tags: folders, directory

I need to create a figure like the following one
[image]

An image shows a directory tree using folders icons. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Have you looked at the `forest` package?

Comment: @ajeh I have just looked at it. It is nice but it does not permit to write inside folders icons

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you really think there is going to be a package which has a `write-inside-folder-icons` among its default options? I think you will wait a long time for a solution in that case ;).

Comment: By the way, `/bin` is now a symbolic link on most systems. (Those which follow the newer standards for the hierarchy. Admittedly, it is a mixed bag at the moment.) Likewise, `/media` is no longer in the top level on many systems.

Comment: @cfr concerning `/bin` that is true, but for `/media`... this is a # ls / on Fedora 21 http://paste.fedoraproject.org/150158/17663141/

Comment: I think fedora has incompletely implemented the new hierarchy though I'm not sure of the details.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's one possibility using [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) and `TikZ`:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\definecolor{fblue}{RGB}{92,144,192}
\definecolor{fgreen}{RGB}{34,162,70}

\newcommand\myfolder[2][fblue]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \draw[fill=#1!82!black] 
    (-20pt,14pt) -- 
    (-17pt,17pt) --
    (-1pt,17pt) --
    (1pt,19pt) --
    (12pt,19pt) --
    (14pt,17pt) --
    (17pt,17pt) --
    (20pt,14pt) -- cycle;
  \draw[line width=0.75pt,white] 
    (-18.5pt,14pt) -- 
    (-15.5pt,16.5pt) --
    (0.5pt,16.5pt) --
    (2pt,18.3pt) --
    (10.5pt,18.3pt) --
    (12.5pt,16.5pt) --
    (15.5pt,16.5pt) --
    (18.5pt,14pt) -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners,top color=#1,bottom color=#1!30] 
    (-23pt,14pt) -- 
    (23pt,14pt) --
    (21pt,-14pt) --
    (-21pt,-14pt) -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners,line width=1pt,white] 
    (-22pt,13pt) -- 
    (22pt,13pt) --
    (20pt,-13pt) --
    (-20pt,-13pt) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{-3pt}{{\ttfamily\small/#2}}}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  parent anchor=south,
  child anchor=north,
  node options={inner sep=11pt},
  l sep=25pt,
  s sep=40pt,
} 
[\myfolder{}
  [\myfolder{bin}]
  [\myfolder{dev}]
  [{\myfolder[fgreen]{home}}
    [{\myfolder[fgreen]{anna}}]
    [{\myfolder[fgreen]{claudio}}]
  ]
  [\myfolder{media}]
  [\myfolder{mnt}]
  [\myfolder{usr}]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The command `\myfolder` has one mandatory argument for the label of the folder and an optional argument for the color.

Comment: (+1) [But mine is more accurate!] Very dispiriting, though. I took an hour longer and mine don't even look like folders ;).

Comment: I bow to your knowledge!

Comment: Is there a way to remove the `/` symbol in `/home` and other folders? I made this mistake when I created the example image

Comment: @Caterpillar Sure. Remove it from the line `\makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{-3pt}{{\ttfamily\small/#2}}}`, so now it is `\makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{-3pt}{{\ttfamily\small #2}}}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Unluckly this command will remove it in folder root too.

Comment: @Caterpillar change the first `\myfolder{}` to `\myfolder{/}`

Comment: so, where are the icons defined?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Wow! Very Impressive. How could you represent and draw a file (for exaple named "report.txt") inside a folder (for example the folder "Claudio"?  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `forest` solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{/forest,
    symlink/.append style={
      opacity=.25,
      text opacity=.5,
      before drawing tree={
        {tikz+={\draw [thick, -{>[]}] (!#1.west) ++(4pt,-1.5pt) arc (315:120:5pt);}}
      },
    },
  }
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      trapezium,
      trapezium angle=95,
      rounded corners=2pt,
      draw,
      fill=blue!50,
    }
    [/
      [/bin, symlink
      ]
      [/boot
      ]
      [/dev
      ]
      [/etc
      ]
      [/home, fill=green!50, for children={fill=green!50}
        [Gwen
        ]
        [Dai
        ]
      ]
      [/mnt
      ]
      [/sbin, symlink
      ]
      [/usr
      ]
      [/var
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forest directories]