# Making a directory tree of folders and files

Tags: forest, directory

How to draw the directory tree image shown below, indicating folders ***and files***?

[image]

To draw the folder tree I used the code from [Making a (simple) directory tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree), but there is no obvious option to include files, and I therefore edited the image in Inkscape, as indicated in red.

The replicated code from Gonzalo Medina post ([Making a (simple) directory tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree)) is shown below

```
    \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{forest}

    \definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
    \definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}

    \def\Size{4pt}
    \tikzset{
      folder/.pic={
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
          (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);  
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
          (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
      }
    }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
      for tree={
        font=\ttfamily,
        grow'=0,
        child anchor=west,
        parent anchor=south,
        anchor=west,
        calign=first,
        inner xsep=7pt,
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor) pic {folder} \forestoption{edge label};
        },
        before typesetting nodes={
          if n=1
            {insert before={[,phantom]}}
            {}
        },
        fit=band,
        before computing xy={l=15pt},
      }  
    [system
      [config
      ]
      [lib
        [Access
        ]
        [Plugin
        ]
      ]
      [templates
      ]
      [tests
      ]
    ]
    \end{forest}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create  a `style` for your file node like this

```
file/.style={edge path={\noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor) \forestoption{edge label};},
         inner xsep=2pt,font=\small\ttfamily
            }
```

**Code**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}

\def\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{
      folder/.pic={
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
          (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);  
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
          (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
      }
    }


 \begin{document}

 \begin{forest}
      for tree={
        font=\ttfamily,
        grow'=0,
        child anchor=west,
        parent anchor=south,
        anchor=west,
        calign=first,
        inner xsep=7pt,
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor) pic {folder} \forestoption{edge label};
        },
        % style for your file node 
        file/.style={edge path={\noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor) \forestoption{edge label};},
          inner xsep=2pt,font=\small\ttfamily
                     },
        before typesetting nodes={
          if n=1
            {insert before={[,phantom]}}
            {}
        },
        fit=band,
        before computing xy={l=15pt},
      }  
    [system
      [config
      ]
      [lib
        [Access
        ]
        [Plugin
        ]
        [file.txt,file
        ]
      ]
      [templates
      ]
      [tests
      ]
    ]
 \end{forest}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Currently the tree is displayed in the center of the page? How to move everything to the left of the page?

Answer (score 22):

This answer has 2 primary purposes.

1. Simplify the existing code by updating it to make use of the facilities offered by current Forest, especially those offered by the `edges` library which provides the `folder` option.
2. Create a `file` pic to match the existing `folder` one, and to enable styles to easily switch between them.

In addition, it has a secondary purpose.

3. Provide an extensible interface for the addition of further `pic` icons, should these be desired.

---

When [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270761/) posted that code, Forest offered no easy out-of-the-box solution supporting this kind of structure. This was why I wrote styles such as `dir tree` and [the answer cited by Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269734/how-to-adjust-large-number-of-nodes-in-forest-environment/269820#269820) in response to requests for this kind of diagram.

Since then, we have an extensively updated and expanded Forest with the beginnings of an expansion system via libraries. One of those already on offer is `edges` which, perhaps surprisingly, supports just this kind of tree.

I would not recommend using the old method unless you are stuck with Forest 1 and cannot update. The support for this kind of tree provided by updated Forest is more flexible, simpler and more robust.

---

First, we add a `pic` for the file icon.

```
  file/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!5, bottom color=folderbg!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
  },
```

This picks up the base folder colours. Obviously, you could change this to use different colours if desired.

Now for some Forest configuration.

```
\forestset{%
  declare autowrapped toks={pic me}{},
```

This is an option to hold the value desired for each node. Eventually, this will take values such as `pic {file}`. By default, it is empty.

We define a style for trees of this kind, `pic dir tree`.

```
  pic dir tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      folder,
      font=\ttfamily,
      grow'=0,
    },
```

Defaults for the tree: `folder` has nothing to do with the `pic`. Rather, it is the name of the style which the Forest `edges` library provides for directory-style trees.

We'll collect the `pic me` settings on parsing the tree. We'll then add them to the `edge path` by appending the option to the value of `edge label`.

```
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        edge label+/.option={pic me},
      },
    },
  },
```

This saves messing around with the path which we've already set to a non-default by using the `folder` style for the tree.

Now for a convenience wrapper. `pic me set` takes 2 arguments. The first is the name of a Forest style to-be-created. The second is the name of a `pic` such as `folder` (in the icon sense) or `file`.

```
  pic me set/.code n args=2{%
    \forestset{%
      #1/.style={%
        inner xsep=2\Size,
        pic me={pic {#2}},
      }
    }
  },
```

Each style so defined will do 2 things. First, it will set a node's `inner xsep` to a value which is not here hard-coded, but dependent on `\Size`. Second, it will set the node's `pic me` option to the relevant value.

We just create 2 such styles for now.

```
  pic me set={directory}{folder},
```

The first, is `directory`. This add the `folder` icon. (We use `directory` rather than `folder` to avoid still further confusion.)

```
  pic me set={file}{file},
```

The second is `file`. No complications here, so we can use the name of the `file` icon.

Further styles can be created in the same way, provided a suitable `pic` is available.

```
}
```

Now to typeset a tree of this kind, we can use the following in the tree's preamble.

```
\begin{forest}
  pic dir tree,
```

This sets up the tree with the options described above.

```
  where level=0{}{% folder icons by default; override using file for file icons
    directory,
  },
```

In our case, we'll set all non-root nodes to use the `directory` style by default, since most of them need folder icons.

We can then write

```
      [file.txt, file
      ]
```

to override the style and use a file icon for the single exception.

[image: folders and files in current Forest]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{%
  folder/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
  },
  file/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!5, bottom color=folderbg!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
  },
}
\forestset{%
  declare autowrapped toks={pic me}{},
  pic dir tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      folder,
      font=\ttfamily,
      grow'=0,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        edge label+/.option={pic me},
      },
    },
  },
  pic me set/.code n args=2{%
    \forestset{%
      #1/.style={%
        inner xsep=2\Size,
        pic me={pic {#2}},
      }
    }
  },
  pic me set={directory}{folder},
  pic me set={file}{file},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  pic dir tree,
  where level=0{}{% folder icons by default; override using file for file icons
    directory,
  },
  [system
    [config
    ]
    [lib
      [Access
      ]
      [Plugin
      ]
      [file.txt, file
      ]
    ]
    [templates
    ]
    [tests
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405253/ if you want a folder icon for the root node.

Comment: unfortunately, the code won't compile, but throw the following errors instead: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/forest/package@options/edges' 
and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`, `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/forest/edge label+/.option', td it. \end{forest}`, `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/folder' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \end{forest}`

Comment: @Bastian You have an old version of Forest. Update your installation of TeX and it should work fine. The error says that you are using v1 of Forest whereas the code requires v2.

Comment: @Bastian As I explain in the question, this answer relies on features of current Forest which were not available when the earlier answer was posted. If you cannot update, just stick with the method in that earlier answer. However, things are much easier and more flexible if you can update and use the approach in my answer.

Comment: How to specify the version of package in latex? What is the equivalent of requirements.txt in latex?

Comment: Currently the tree is displayed in the center of the page? How to move everything to the left of the page?