# pgfkeys error: I do not know the key '/tikz/folder/.pic'

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, forest

I try to use [anwser](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328886/making-a-directory-tree-of-folders-and-files/328987#328987), but when I compile, it output:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/folder/.pic' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}


\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}

\def\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{
    folder/.pic={
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
        (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);  
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
        (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{forest test}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            font=\ttfamily,
            grow'=0,
            child anchor=west,
            parent anchor=south,
            anchor=west,
            calign=first,
            inner xsep=7pt,
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
                (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor) pic {folder} \forestoption{edge label};
            },
            before typesetting nodes={
                if n=1
                {insert before={[,phantom]}}
                {}
            },
            fit=band,
            before computing xy={l=15pt},
        }  
        [system
            [config
            ]
            [lib
                [Access
                ]
                [Plugin
                ]
            ]
            [templates
            ]
            [tests
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is my package info:

```
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76）
Package: forest 2013/10/17 v1.04 Drawing (linguistic) trees
```

Comment: What version of PGF/Ti*k*Z are you using? I suspect it is rather old. If so, you need to update. (And if you update, you could use cleaner code for Forest, too, but the main thing is that you need `.pic`s.)

Comment: @cfr how can I check the version?

Comment: Look in the log? That's easiest.

Comment: @cfr I checked error log and i did not find version info

Comment: @cfr got it, I find it in `*.log` file and I put it in my question

Comment: You TeX is very old. Current version of `forest` is `2017/07/14 v2.1.5` and of `tikz` `2015/08/07 v3.0.1a`. With the current versions (and even with last available updates for TeX Live 2013) your example does work without any problem. So I would say: You should update.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem can be solved by an update of the outdated TeX installation.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I should update whole tex or just package?

Comment: I do not know which TeX distribution you are using and I do not know your project. However, if you are using TeX Live or MacTeX you should [install a new one](https://tug.org/texlive). Otherwise you would have to update packages manually which could be a lot of work, if you have also to update depending packages. If you are using MiKTeX 2.9 you should update at least `forest`, `tikz` and `pgf` and see, which other packages need updates because of dependencies. But with such an old TeX installation it could be easier to do a complete update.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I use Ubuntu and current Tex was installed by apt

Comment: Even the current LTS version of Ubuntu has a [newer TeX Live](https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial/texlive). You could either ubgrade your Ubuntu or [install vanilla TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html).

Comment: I had the same problem and it turned out that there was a really old version of pgf (2.10 as well) still installed (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, after several upgrades), presumably as a dependency of some old latex beamer installation (still in the `latex-beamer` package instead of `texlive-latex-recommended`). `apt-get purge pgf` helped, so that the newer version could take over. As a side effect, this also removed the outdated `latex-beamer`.

Comment: I get the same error with tikz version `2015/08/07 v3.0.1a` and forest version `2017/07/14 v2.1.5`, anyone has an idea?