# How can I make directory trees with icons that handle page-breaks?

Tags: page-breaking, tikz-trees, forest

First time poster.

I've been trying to work out how to combine the answers presented to these questions:
[Directory tree on multiple pages using Forest package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356749/directory-tree-on-multiple-pages-using-forest-package)

[How to insert folder icon in root node with forest package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405192/how-to-insert-folder-icon-in-root-node-with-forest-package)

And a few other related variations on these questions on SE.  The end goal is to be able to produce filesystem trees / directory trees in larger PDF documents by transforming the XML output of the [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) command (as `tree -X directory`) using the following set of pipes:

```
sed '1,2d' tree-output.xml |tac | sed '1,5d' | tac | sed 's/<file  name=\"/[/g' | sed 's/\"><\/file>/]/g' | sed 's/<directory name=\"/[/g' | sed 's/\">//g' | sed 's/<\/directory>/]/g' >> transformed-tree.tex
```

And to then include the transformed tree in a TeX file using `\include{transformed-tree}`
So far the set of pipes work...and it seems to output things correctly for forest to parse into a folder tree. The transformation is included just as background information. I know the output differs from that found in the code below (was manually tinkering with the `[ filename, file]` notation from [Making a directory tree of folders and files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328886/making-a-directory-tree-of-folders-and-files/328987#328987)
and from [How to insert folder icon in root node with forest package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405192/how-to-insert-folder-icon-in-root-node-with-forest-package/405253#405253))

**What I am having trouble with is with having that tree display correctly when the tree must span multiple pages.**

I do not yet know TeX enough to know where I'm going wrong. Here is a (non)working example. It compiles, but the page-breaks make the folder/file icons stop working, and the vertical spacing is all out of whack:

```
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405192/how-to-insert-folder-icon-in-root-node-with-forest-package/405253#405253
% and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356749/directory-tree-on-multiple-pages-using-forest-package
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{%
  folder/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
  },
  file/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!5, bottom color=folderbg!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
  },
}
\forestset{%
  declare autowrapped toks={pic me}{},
  declare boolean register={pic root},
  pic root=0,
  pic dir tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      folder,
      font=\ttfamily,
      grow'=0,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        edge label+/.option={pic me},
      },
      if pic root={
        tikz+={
          \pic at ([xshift=\Size].west) {folder};
        },
        align={l}
      }{},
    },
  },
  pic me set/.code n args=2{%
    \forestset{%
      #1/.style={%
        inner xsep=2\Size,
        pic me={pic {#2}},
      }
    }
  },
  pic me set={directory}{folder},
  pic me set={file}{file},
}
%begin from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356749/directory-tree-on-multiple-pages-using-forest-package
\def\hiddenparcommand{\par}
\newcommand\otherhiddenparcommand{\par\noindent}
\newcommand\hiddencommacommand{, }
\forestset{%
  declare keylist register={split here ids},% the list of nodes to split the tree at
  split here ids={},
  declare keylist register={split here interjects},% the list of comments to put in between the tree parts
  split here interjects={},
  declare keylist={split here auto siblings}{},% a list to hold the siblings which need edge restoration
  declare toks register=split here toks,
  declare dimen register=tmpdima,
  tmpdima'=0pt,
  declare dimen register=tmpdimb,
  tmpdimb'=0pt,
  declare dimen register=tmpdimc,
  tmpdimc'=0pt,
  to widest/.style={
    tikz+={\path (\forestregister{tempdima}, \forestoption{y}) -- (\forestregister{tempdimb}, \forestoption{y});},
  },
  hide commas/.style={%
    split here toks+={\hiddencommacommand},
    split here toks+={#1},
  },
  split dir tree pre/.style={%
    label={[text=gray, anchor=north, font=\scriptsize]below:{[cont.]}{}},
  },
  split dir tree post/.style={%
    label={[font=\scriptsize, anchor=south, text=gray]above:{[cont.]}{}},
  },
  split dir tree auto post/.style={% this gets applied to the first node after a break
    split dir tree post,
    tempkeylistc'={},
    tmpdimb/.option=y,
    for nodewalk={
      while={
        > ORw2+d _+d < On=! & {y}{tmpdimb}{##2-##1} {\textheight-#1} {n'}{1}%
      }{
        next,
        tempkeylistc/.option=name
      }%
    }{},
    % save the list
    split here auto siblings/.register=tempkeylistc,
    tikz+/.process={% this tries to redraw the edges to the following siblings
      OOw2{edge}{id}%
      {%
        \path [##1] (!u.parent anchor |- .north) ++(\forestregister{folder indent},1ex) coordinate (before ##2) |- (.child anchor);
        \edef\tempa{\foresteoption{split here auto siblings}}
        \foreach \i in \tempa \path [##1] (before ##2) |- ({forest cs:\i.child anchor});
      }%
    },
  },
  split dir tree/.code={%
    \forestset{%
      draw tree stage/.style={
        for root'={
          tempdima/.min={%
            >OOw2+d{x}{min x}{####1+####2}%
          }{tree},
          tempdimb/.max={%
            >OOw2+d{x}{max x}{####1+####2}%
          }{tree},
          for tree={%
            to widest,
          },
        },
        tempcountb'=-1,
        do until={%
          strequal((split_here_ids),"")
        }{%
          tempkeylistb'={},
          tempkeylista'={},
          split register={split here ids}{,}{tempcounta,tempkeylistb+},
          split register={split here interjects}{,}{temptoksa,tempkeylista+},
          split here ids'/.register=tempkeylistb,
          split here interjects'/.register=tempkeylista,
        % Sašo Živanović: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28484520#28484520
         for nodewalk={%
           draw tree processing order/.style={%
             filter={tree}{> ORw+n< OR> & {id}{tempcounta}{########1+1}{id}{tempcountb}}%
           }%
         }{},
          for root'={draw tree},
          TeX/.process={Rw{temptoksa}{\otherhiddenparcommand ####1\hiddenparcommand}},
          tempcountb'/.register=tempcounta,
        },
        for nodewalk={%
          draw tree processing order/.style={%
            filter={tree}{>OR>{id}{tempcountb}}%
          }%
        }{},
        for root'={draw tree},
      },
    }%
  },
  split dir here auto/.style n args=2{%
    split dir tree pre,
    !next node.split dir tree auto post=#2,
    split here ids+/.option=id,
%     !next node.split resume here ids+/.option=id,
    split={#1}{,}{split here toks,hide commas},
    split here interjects/.register=split here toks,
  },
  split dir tree auto/.style={%
    split dir tree,
    before drawing tree={%
      tempdima/.max={y}{tree},
      tempdimc/.register=tempdima,
      tempdimd/.min={y}{tree},
      tempdima-/.register=tempdimd,
      tempdimb'=\textheight,
      tmpdima'=10ex,
      tmpdimc'=\pagetotal,
      while={%
        >RR>{tempdima}{tempdimb}%
      }{%
        for nodewalk={%
          root',
          until={%
            > ROw2+d RRw2+d > {tempdimc}{y}{##1-##2} {tmpdima}{tmpdimc}{\textheight-##2-##1}%
          }{next node},
          previous node,
          split dir here auto/.process={R_w2{tmpdima}{continued}{{##2}{##1}}},
          next node,
          tempdima/.option=y,
          tempdimc/.register=tempdima,
          tempdima-/.register=tempdimd,
          tmpdima'=15ex,
          tmpdimc'=0pt
        }{},
      },
    },
  },
}
%end from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356749/directory-tree-on-multiple-pages-using-forest-package
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  pic dir tree,
  pic root,
  for tree={% folder icons by default; override using file for file icons
    directory,
    folder,% this and next 2 lines from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356749/directory-tree-on-multiple-pages-using-forest-package
    grow'=0,
    fit=band
  },
  split dir tree auto, % line from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339669/automatic-page-break-with-forest-spanning-a-tree-over-multiple-pages
  [  .
    [ 1.txt, file ]
    [ MyShelve, file ]
    [ Pipfile, file ]
    [ Pipfile.lock, file ]
    [ cl.py, file ]
    [ clasync.py, file ]
    [ ex1.py, file ]
    [ ex10-2.py, file ]
    [ ex11-3.py, file ]
    [ ex12-4.py, file ]
    [ ex12-4a.py, file ]
    [ ex13.py, file ]
    [ ex14.py, file ]
    [ ex15.py, file ]
    [ ex16.py, file ]
    [ ex17-loops.py, file ]
    [ ex17.py, file ]
    [ ex18.py, file ]
    [ freewrite
      [ devel
        [ fwprompt.py, file ]
        [ makephrases.py, file ]
        [ prompt2.py, file ]
       ]
      [ makephrases.py, file ]
      [ phraseprompt.py, file ]
      [ phrases.txt, file ]
     ]
    [ jt.py, file ]
    [ jt1.py, file ]
    [ jt2.py, file ]
    [ jt2a.py, file ]
    [ jt3.py, file ]
    [ jt4.py, file ]
    [ jt5.py, file ]
    [ jt6.py, file ]
    [ jt7.py, file ]
    [ jt8.py, file ]
    [ python-script-examples
      [ README.md , file]
      [ Vagrantfile , file]
      [ automate-ssh-with-netmiko
        [ collect-cdp-information.py, file ]
        [ result.html, file ]
       ]
      [ cisco-ios-config-parameter-extraction
       ]
      [ cisco-nx-api-example
        [ interface-description-cleaner.py, file ]
       ]
      [ config-generator-with-custom-filters
        [ config-generator-with-custom-filter.py, file ]
        [ ip-interface-config.jinja2, file ]
        [ parameters.json, file ]
       ]
      [ config-generator-with-python-and-jinja2
        [ parameters.csv, file ]
        [ parameters.json, file ]
        [ switch.j2, file ]
       ]
      [ create-hsrp-interface-configuration
        [ create-hsrp-interface-configuration.py, file ]
       ]
      [ json-code-example
        [ cl.py, file ]
        [ cl1.py, file ]
        [ cl2.py, file ]
       ]
      [ jupyter-config
        [ 10-nb-import-hook.py, file ]
        [ about.ipynb, file ]
        [ jupyter-notebook.upstart, file ]
       ]
      [ migrate-static-arp-entries
        [ create-migration-templates.py, file ]
       ]
      [ notebooks
        [ Introduction to the ipaddress module with IPv4.ipynb, file ]
        [ Introduction to the ipaddress module with IPv6.ipynb, file ]
        [ pandas
          [ Merge DataFrames in Pandas.ipynb, file ]
         ]
       ]
      [ parse-show-inventory-with-textfsm
       ]
      [ requirements.txt, file ]
      [ setup.yaml, file ]
       ]
     ]
    [ shellsets.txt , file]
    [ skele-cli
      [ MANIFEST.in , file]
      [ README.rst , file]
      [ setup.cfg , file]
      [ setup.py , file]
      [ skele
        [ cli.py , file]
        [ commands
          [ base.py , file]
          [ hello.py, file ]
         ]
       ]
      [ tests
        [ commands
         ]
       ]
     ]
    [ test
      [ a
        [ boo, file ]
        [ boo123, file ]
       ]
      [ b
        [ boo12, file ]
        [ boo123 , file]
        [ c
          [ boot, file ]
          [ boot1, file ]
          [ boot13, file ]
         ]
       ]
      [ boo ]
      [ boo1 ]
      [ boo12 ]
      [ boo123 ]
     ]
    [ todo.txt, file ]
    [ treestuff
      [ dirtree.pl , file]
      [ familytree.pdf , file]
      [ familytree.tex , file]
      [ forest-close.tex , file]
      [ forest-example-2.aux, file ]
      [ forest-example-2.dvi, file ]
      [ forest-example-2.fls, file ]
      [ forest-example-2.log , file]
      [ forest-example-2.pdf, file ]
      [ forest-example-2.tex, file ]
      [ forest-header.tex, file ]
      [ forest-standalone-frame.tex, file ]
      [ forest-start.tex, file ]
      [ forest.ex.tex, file ]
      [ forest.ex1.tex, file ]
      [ fortt.pdf, file ]
      [ fortt.tex, file ]
      [ fortt1.tex, file ]
      [ fortt2.pdf, file ]
      [ fortt2.tex, file ]
      [ fortt3.pdf, file ]
      [ fortt3.tex, file ]
      [ fortt4.pdf, file ]
      [ fortt4.tex, file ]
      [ fortt5.pdf, file ]
      [ fortt5.tex, file ]
      [ testtree.xml, file ]
      [ textree.pdf, file ]
      [ textree.tex, file ]
      [ tikz-tree-sample.tex, file ]
      [ tree.forest.tex, file ]
      [ tree.json, file ]
      [ tree.xml, file ]
      [ tree1.xml, file ]
      [ tree1.xml.forest, file ]
      [ tree2.xml.tex, file ]
      [ treedir.tex, file ]
      [ treetest.tex, file ]
      [ xmltree.to.forest.txt, file ]
     ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

This is what the output looks like (output pdf burst into single pages using ghostscript, each page exported as PNG using Preview.app):
[image: page 1/4 of the output]
[image: page 2/4 of the output]
[image: page 3/4 of the output]
[image: page 4/4 of the output]

You may have noticed `dirtree.pl` listed among the files in the example tree above.  Trying to use `forest` instead of `dirtree` because I cannot read dirtree as easily as forest trees and am aiming to generate good looking directory structure trees.

**EDITS BEGIN HERE**

**Followup Q:** Would an answer to my question be different if there was need to arbitrarily include trees in a document via ~~`\include{}`s?~~ `\input{}` ?
I ask because I noticed that these uses of the `forest` package seem to require code (`\forestset{}`) before and after `\begin{document}` and I was thinking of generating documents using snippets of code where preambles and code would be put together using a bash script...with the actual *forest* generated by a variation of the pipeline above...

An alternative solution might be to generate the forest tree graphic as a standalone pdf using this code...

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{%
  folder/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom     color=folderbg] (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++    (.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom     color=folderbg] (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
  },
  file/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!5, bottom     color=folderbg!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |-     (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++    (-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
  },
}
\forestset{%
  declare autowrapped toks={pic me}{},
  declare boolean register={pic root},
  pic root=0,
  pic dir tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      folder,
      font=\ttfamily,
      grow'=0,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        edge label+/.option={pic me},
      },
      if pic root={
        tikz+={
          \pic at ([xshift=\Size].west) {folder};
        },
        align={l}
      }{},
    },
  },
  pic me set/.code n args=2{%
    \forestset{%
      #1/.style={%
        inner xsep=2\Size,
        pic me={pic {#2}},
      }
    }
  },
  pic me set={directory}{folder},
  pic me set={file}{file},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  pic dir tree,
  pic root,
  for tree={% folder icons by default; override using file for file icons
    directory,
  },
\input{transformed-tree}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Where `transformed-tree` refers to a `transformed-tree.tex` (as above in transformation pipeline).

The output looks like this:
[image: standalone tree pdf]

And I was able to break it up into multiple pages using this code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{minimal}
\usepackage[pdftex,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[viewport={0 3030pt 400pt 2525pt},clip]{ftrn2a.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[viewport={0 2525pt 400pt 2020pt},clip]{ftrn2a.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[viewport={0 2020pt 400pt 1515pt},clip]{ftrn2a.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[viewport={0 1515pt 400pt 1010pt},clip]{ftrn2a.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[viewport={0 1010pt 400pt 505pt},clip]{ftrn2a.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[viewport={0 505pt 400pt 0},clip]{ftrn2a.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I first had to figure out the total size of the standalone tree pdf... I did that with this:
`pdfinfo -box ftrn2a.pdf | grep "Page size" | cut -d ' ' -f 8,10 | echo "`cut -d ' ' -f 2`/ 750" | bc -l | cut -d '.' -f 1` and then used a calculator after figuring out that about 500pt would look OK per page...

The output from this has its own issues...such as cutting across words and icons...
[image: cross-page divisions on output from cropping included standalone pdf]

While this might work in a pinch, I believe lots of time might need to be spent tweaking the viewport settings to avoid cutting across any text.

Comment: Is this just the wrong approach? Would it be easier to produce a standalone pdf and then to use the pdfpages package with `\includepdf` ? or some similar approach?

Comment: You ought not use `\include{}` here at all. That's for things like entire chapters. You probably want `\input{}` or similar instead. I don't understand the question about arbitrary `\include{}` anyway. What do you mean by this exactly? Why would it be a problem if you needed code before and after `\begin{document}`? I can't imagine why you'd need `\forestset{}` before and after `\begin{document}`. Can you give an example? Why do you think this is required? That is: I can't see why that's required but, if it is, I don't see why that's a problem, but using `\include{}` here is anyway wrong.

Comment: If I take the `pic` stuff out, I can't compile it at all. Can you post the working version you have without the icons?

Comment: re: questions about `\include{}` and `\input{}` The aim was to be able to cobble together trees using multiple files and *nix shell utilities to automate the creation of trees.

Comment: So? `\include{}` is wrong and not at all like `\input{}`. Why can't you use `\input`?

Comment: strictly speaking, there is no non-icons working version. I was unable to add the icons `\forestset{}` code from [How to insert folder icon in root node with forest package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405192/how-to-insert-folder-icon-in-root-node-with-forest-package/405253#405253) to [Directory tree on multiple pages using Forest package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356749/directory-tree-on-multiple-pages-using-forest-package) so I went the other way and put the page splitting `\forestset{}` code into the working icons example.

Comment: I get strange things on page 2 whether I add icons or not.

Comment: Dang. I need to re-read the forest documentation. Am I just asking too much of the forest package?

Comment: Well, it is not exactly designed with page breaks in mind! But the don't-use-`\include` has nothing to do with Forest.

Answer (score 1):

Non-working code, but closer. (It compiles, but the second page is wrong for reasons my brain doesn't currently think obvious.)

Code is basically from [Directory tree on multiple pages using Forest package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356749/directory-tree-on-multiple-pages-using-forest-package), except the folder/file shapes are from somebody else, probably, but I am blanking on where or who. There's nothing else here right now - nothing new. But it still works better icon-wise than the code in the question. (It is the edge which is the bugbear.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\newsavebox{\diricon}
\newsavebox{\fileicon}
\sbox{\diricon}{\tikz{\filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);}}
\sbox{\fileicon}{\tikz{\filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!5, bottom color=folderbg!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;}}
% addaswyd o gôd Sašo Živanović: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296771/
\def\hiddenparcommand{\par}
\newcommand\otherhiddenparcommand{\par\noindent}
\newcommand\hiddencommacommand{, }
\forestset{%
  declare keylist register={split here ids},% the list of nodes to split the tree at
  split here ids={},
  declare keylist register={split here interjects},% the list of comments to put in between the tree parts
  split here interjects={},
  declare keylist={split here auto siblings}{},% a list to hold the siblings which need edge restoration
  declare toks register=split here toks,
  declare dimen register=tmpdima,
  tmpdima'=0pt,
  declare dimen register=tmpdimb,
  tmpdimb'=0pt,
  declare dimen register=tmpdimc,
  tmpdimc'=0pt,
  to widest/.style={
    tikz+={\path (\forestregister{tempdima}, \forestoption{y}) -- (\forestregister{tempdimb}, \forestoption{y});},
  },
  hide commas/.style={%
    split here toks+={\hiddencommacommand},
    split here toks+={#1},
  },
  split dir tree pre/.style={%
    label={[text=gray, anchor=north, font=\scriptsize]below:{[cont.]}{}},
  },
  split dir tree post/.style={%
    label={[font=\scriptsize, anchor=south, text=gray]above:{[cont.]}{}},
  },
  split dir tree auto post/.style={% this gets applied to the first node after a break
    split dir tree post,
    tempkeylistc'={},
    tmpdimb/.option=y,
    for nodewalk={
      while={
        > ORw2+d _+d < On=! & {y}{tmpdimb}{##2-##1} {\textheight-#1} {n'}{1}%
      }{
        next,
        tempkeylistc/.option=name
      }%
    }{},
    % save the list
    split here auto siblings/.register=tempkeylistc,
    tikz+/.process={% this tries to redraw the edges to the following siblings
      OOw2{edge}{id}%
      {%
        \path [##1] (!u.parent anchor |- .north) ++(\forestregister{folder indent},1ex) coordinate (before ##2) |- (.child anchor);
        \edef\tempa{\foresteoption{split here auto siblings}}
        \foreach \i in \tempa \path [##1] (before ##2) |- ({forest cs:\i.child anchor});
      }%
    },
  },
  split dir tree/.code={%
    \forestset{%
      draw tree stage/.style={
        for root'={
          tempdima/.min={%
            >OOw2+d{x}{min x}{####1+####2}%
          }{tree},
          tempdimb/.max={%
            >OOw2+d{x}{max x}{####1+####2}%
          }{tree},
          for tree={%
            to widest,
          },
        },
        tempcountb'=-1,
        do until={%
          strequal((split_here_ids),"")
        }{%
          tempkeylistb'={},
          tempkeylista'={},
          split register={split here ids}{,}{tempcounta,tempkeylistb+},
          split register={split here interjects}{,}{temptoksa,tempkeylista+},
          split here ids'/.register=tempkeylistb,
          split here interjects'/.register=tempkeylista,
        % Sašo Živanović: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28484520#28484520
         for nodewalk={%
           draw tree processing order/.style={%
             filter={tree}{> ORw+n< OR> & {id}{tempcounta}{########1+1}{id}{tempcountb}}%
           }%
         }{},
          for root'={draw tree},
          TeX/.process={Rw{temptoksa}{\otherhiddenparcommand ####1\hiddenparcommand}},
          tempcountb'/.register=tempcounta,
        },
        for nodewalk={%
          draw tree processing order/.style={%
            filter={tree}{>OR>{id}{tempcountb}}%
          }%
        }{},
        for root'={draw tree},
      },
    }%
  },
  split dir here auto/.style n args=2{%
    split dir tree pre,
    !next node.split dir tree auto post=#2,
    split here ids+/.option=id,
%     !next node.split resume here ids+/.option=id,
    split={#1}{,}{split here toks,hide commas},
    split here interjects/.register=split here toks,
  },
  split dir tree auto/.style={%
    split dir tree,
    before drawing tree={%
      tempdima/.max={y}{tree},
      tempdimc/.register=tempdima,
      tempdimd/.min={y}{tree},
      tempdima-/.register=tempdimd,
      tempdimb'=\textheight,
      tmpdima'=10ex,
      tmpdimc'=\pagetotal,
      while={%
        >RR>{tempdima}{tempdimb}%
      }{%
        for nodewalk={%
          root',
          until={%
            > ROw2+d RRw2+d > {tempdimc}{y}{##1-##2} {tmpdima}{tmpdimc}{\textheight-##2-##1}%
          }{next node},
          previous node,
          split dir here auto/.process={R_w2{tmpdima}{continued}{{##2}{##1}}},
          next node,
          tempdima/.option=y,
          tempdimc/.register=tempdima,
          tempdima-/.register=tempdimd,
          tmpdima'=15ex,
          tmpdimc'=0pt
        }{},
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={% folder icons by default; override using file for file icons
    folder,
    grow'=0,
    fit=band,
  },
  split dir tree auto,
  before typesetting nodes={
    where n children=0{content/.wrap value={\usebox{\fileicon} #1}}{content/.wrap value={\usebox{\diricon} #1}}
  }
  [  .
    [1.txt]
    [MyShelve]
    [Pipfile]
    [Pipfile.lock]
    [cl.py]
    [clasync.py]
    [ex1.py]
    [ex10-2.py]
    [ex11-3.py]
    [ex12-4.py]
    [ex12-4a.py]
    [ex13.py]
    [ex14.py]
    [ex15.py]
    [ex16.py]
    [ex17-loops.py]
    [ex17.py]
    [ex18.py]
    [freewrite
      [devel
        [fwprompt.py]
        [makephrases.py]
        [prompt2.py]
       ]
      [makephrases.py]
      [phraseprompt.py]
      [phrases.txt]
     ]
    [jt.py]
    [jt1.py]
    [jt2.py]
    [jt2a.py]
    [jt3.py]
    [jt4.py]
    [jt5.py]
    [jt6.py]
    [jt7.py]
    [jt8.py]
    [python-script-examples
      [README.md]
      [Vagrantfile]
      [automate-ssh-with-netmiko
        [collect-cdp-information.py]
        [result.html]
       ]
      [cisco-ios-config-parameter-extraction
       ]
      [cisco-nx-api-example
        [interface-description-cleaner.py]
       ]
      [config-generator-with-custom-filters
        [config-generator-with-custom-filter.py]
        [ip-interface-config.jinja2]
        [parameters.json]
       ]
      [config-generator-with-python-and-jinja2
        [parameters.csv]
        [parameters.json]
        [switch.j2]
       ]
      [create-hsrp-interface-configuration
        [create-hsrp-interface-configuration.py]
       ]
      [json-code-example
        [cl.py]
        [cl1.py]
        [cl2.py]
       ]
      [jupyter-config
        [10-nb-import-hook.py]
        [about.ipynb]
        [jupyter-notebook.upstart]
       ]
      [migrate-static-arp-entries
        [create-migration-templates.py]
       ]
      [notebooks
        [Introduction to the ipaddress module with IPv4.ipynb ]
        [Introduction to the ipaddress module with IPv6.ipynb ]
        [pandas
          [Merge DataFrames in Pandas.ipynb ]
         ]
       ]
      [parse-show-inventory-with-textfsm
       ]
      [requirements.txt]
      [setup.yaml]
       ]
     ]
    [shellsets.txt]
    [skele-cli
      [MANIFEST.in]
      [README.rst]
      [setup.cfg]
      [setup.py]
      [skele
        [cli.py]
        [commands
          [base.py]
          [hello.py]
         ]
       ]
      [tests
        [commands
         ]
       ]
     ]
    [test
      [a
        [boo]
        [boo123]
       ]
      [b
        [boo12]
        [boo123]
        [c
          [boot]
          [boot1]
          [boot13]
         ]
       ]
      [boo ]
      [boo1 ]
      [boo12 ]
      [boo123 ]
     ]
    [todo.txt]
    [treestuff
      [dirtree.pl]
      [familytree.pdf]
      [familytree.tex]
      [forest-close.tex]
      [forest-example-2.aux]
      [forest-example-2.dvi]
      [forest-example-2.fls]
      [forest-example-2.log]
      [forest-example-2.pdf]
      [forest-example-2.tex]
      [forest-header.tex]
      [forest-standalone-frame.tex]
      [forest-start.tex]
      [forest.ex.tex]
      [forest.ex1.tex]
      [fortt.pdf]
      [fortt.tex]
      [fortt1.tex]
      [fortt2.pdf]
      [fortt2.tex]
      [fortt3.pdf]
      [fortt3.tex]
      [fortt4.pdf]
      [fortt4.tex]
      [fortt5.pdf]
      [fortt5.tex]
      [testtree.xml]
      [textree.pdf]
      [textree.tex]
      [tikz-tree-sample.tex]
      [tree.forest.tex]
      [tree.json]
      [tree.xml]
      [tree1.xml]
      [tree1.xml.forest]
      [tree2.xml.tex]
      [treedir.tex]
      [treetest.tex]
      [xmltree.to.forest.txt]
     ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right. about the code. I think both are yours! (thanks for that, by the way!) I started with your answer here: [insert folder icon in root mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405192/how-to-insert-folder-icon-in-root-node-with-forest-package/) and added the splitting `\forestset{}` code from your answer here: [Directory Tree on multiple pages using forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356749/directory-tree-on-multiple-pages-using-forest-package)

Comment: Well, this adds icons within the nodes, which is simpler. However, strange things on page 2 regardless.

Comment: found an error in both sets of code above - an errant `]` just after `[ setup.yaml ]` that should be at the end. fixing it does not prevent page2 shenanigans. I still do not understand the documentation well enough to fix this. will keep reading and experimenting.

Comment: @atsu 'both sets'? You mean in the question and answer? (It isn't really an error in the answer, I guess, since I don't know where it is supposed to go!)

Comment: @atsu I have something which works a bit better, but doesn't really work. (Right now, pages 1-6 look OK-ish, 7 is wrong and even 2-6 have missing edges.)

Comment: sorry about the lack of clarity. Yes in both the question and the answer, there was an errant bracket which sometimes ended the initial tree early, and started a new tree just after `setup.yaml`. I still do not understand how that code works well enough to fix it. In particular I do not know how registers work in this context...i.e. `>OOw2+d{x}{min x}{####1+####2}%`

Comment: Some edits were made to main question above to describe alternative approach of using `\includegraphics{}` with viewports to display parts of a standalone tree.

Comment: @atsu That doesn't use registers, but options. Look at the bit on the argument processor. The `>` triggers the processor. The rest is parsed in accordance with the definitions given in the argument processor section of the manual. For example, we have `O` for option, option, `w` for wrap two arguments, `+` for chaining and `d` for interpret as dimension. `x` and `min x` are options. The next bit adds them as dimensions.

Comment: Any tips on documentation I can read to learn to understand these kinds of things? Have so-far learned by doing, and now I'm coming up short trying to understand forest and tikz documentation. Just started working through the TeX book.