# Making a directory tree with custom symbols (symbol for MATLAB file)

Tags: forest, trees, includegraphics, directory, icon

I am trying to draw a directory tree. As the tree should visualize the structure of a MATLAB framework, i would love to represent the matlab files with the corresponding icon, e.g. [image]

I found the following code (which i dont really understand^^) on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405253

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{%
  folder/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
  },
  file/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!5, bottom color=folderbg!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
  },
}
\forestset{%
  declare autowrapped toks={pic me}{},
  declare boolean register={pic root},
  pic root=0,
  pic dir tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      folder,
      font=\ttfamily,
      grow'=0,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        edge label+/.option={pic me},
      },
      if pic root={
        tikz+={
          \pic at ([xshift=\Size].west) {folder};
        },
        align={l}
      }{},
    },
  },
  pic me set/.code n args=2{%
    \forestset{%
      #1/.style={%
        inner xsep=2\Size,
        pic me={pic {#2}},
      }
    }
  },
  pic me set={directory}{folder},
  pic me set={file}{file},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  pic dir tree,
  pic root,
  for tree={% folder icons by default; override using file for file icons
    directory,
  },
  [folder
    [folder
      [matlab\_file.m, file
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This example does pretty much what i want, but i would like to change the symbol bevor the *matlab_file.m* to a custom symbol, like the picture above. Is there a way to get this done?

Originally i wanted to use the real icon as shown in the windows explorer. This symbol is a .ico file, which makes it a bit more difficult (as i suppose). I also couldn't uploade it here, cause the format is not supported. If someone whants to try it, the above picture can be downloaded as .ico here: http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i89749/alecive/flatwoken/Apps-Matlab.ico

But i will allready be happy if its working for .png pictures instead of .ico icons.

Comment: `\tikzset{folder/.pic={\node{\includegraphics[width=...]{<some graphics>};}}}`?

Comment: Yeah, that works ^^. Thanks! I tryed the same, but without the ```\node{}```.

Comment: What should we do with this question then? Do you want to self-answer (you were almost there)?

Comment: I answererd it now, i already thougt about that yesterday, but i don't want to "steal" your correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Schrödinger's cat the solution is not to difficult, just replace the `file/.pic={...},` line with

```
file/.pic={\node{\includegraphics[width=10pt]{<some graphics>}};},
```

Works perfectly fine.