# Bad alignement with forest package when drawing folder tree

Tags: forest

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\definecolor{foldercolor}{RGB}{124,166,198}

\tikzset{pics/folder/.style={code={%
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum size=#1](-foldericon){};
    \node[folder style, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.3*#1, minimum height=0.6*#1, above right, xshift=0.05*#1] at (-foldericon.west){};
    \node[folder style, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=#1] at (-foldericon.center){};}
    },
    pics/folder/.default={20pt},
    folder style/.style={draw=foldercolor!80!black,top color=foldercolor!40,bottom color=foldercolor}
}

\forestset{is file/.style={edge path'/.expanded={%
        ([xshift=\forestregister{folder indent}]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)},
        inner sep=1pt},
    this folder size/.style={edge path'/.expanded={%
        ([xshift=\forestregister{folder indent}]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor) pic[solid]{folder=#1}}, inner xsep=0.6*#1},
    folder tree indent/.style={before computing xy={l=#1}},
    folder icons/.style={folder, this folder size=#1, folder tree indent=3*#1},
    folder icons/.default={12pt},
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={font=\sffamily, grow'=0,
    folder indent=.9em, folder icons,
    edge=densely dotted}
    [main folder
      [images, this folder size=20pt
          [wallpapers]
          [logo.pdf, is file]]
      [tex-files
          [chapter1.tex, is file]]
      [main.tex, is file]
      [main.aux, is file]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The "main folder" text isn't centered above the line. How can I change it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide us with the source of your code, this has [many advantages](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7725/121799). And are you aware of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328987/121799)?

Comment: @marmot Thank you, I didn't get this answer through my research. This looks far better than what I had. Solved.

Comment: Whenever you want to draw a forest tree (or even "not a tree" ;-), it's a good idea to look up [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr)'s posts. ;-)

Comment: It isn't exactly 'bad alignment'. More 'alignment I don't want'. :-) I assumed initially the 'bad alignment' referred to the edges crossing the folder icons.