# Package forest: create a directory structure with comments

Tags: forest, directory

I would like to create a folder structure with comments using the forest package. I found really nice directory structure like the one from [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328886/making-a-directory-tree-of-folders-and-files) made with forest but I don't understand how to add comments with a different style as it is show in the figure below:

[image: Directory structure with comments]

Thanks a lot for your help!

Paul

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please show what your tried so far? Probably start adapting the code from the linked answer to fit the tree structure in the left half of your image?

Answer (score 5):

Adapting the code from [cfr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328987/2693) which substantially improved Gonzalo's code, using the current version of `forest`, you can simply make a macro to introduce the annotations on the folder/file names:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{%
  folder/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
  },
  file/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!5, bottom color=folderbg!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
  },
}
\forestset{%
  declare autowrapped toks={pic me}{},
  pic dir tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      folder,
      font=\itshape,
      grow'=0,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        edge label+/.option={pic me},
      },
    },
  },
  pic me set/.code n args=2{%
    \forestset{%
      #1/.style={%
        inner xsep=2\Size,
        pic me={pic {#2}},
      }
    }
  },
  pic me set={directory}{folder},
  pic me set={file}{file},
}
\newcommand{\fname}[2]{\begin{tabular}{m{1cm}@{\quad}m{4cm}}#1 & \normalfont#2\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  pic dir tree,
  where level=0{}{% folder icons by default; override using file for file icons
    directory,
  },
  [system
    [\fname{config}{A comment about this folder}
    ]
    [lib
      [Access
      ]
      [Plugin
      ]
      [\fname{file.txt}{A comment about this file}, file
      ]
    ]
    [templates
    ]
    [tests
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Hey Alan, thanks a lot for that quick replay!

Comment: Hey this looks awesome. How can I make manual line breaks in the comments? Actually, I want to list file contents here...

Comment: @user2291758 Because it's a `tabular` you can't use \\ but you can use `\newline` instead.