# Forest: Directory listing with files and file contents

Tags: forest

This expands on a number of questions of file listings using forest. The most similar solution to my desired one is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524104/package-forest-create-a-directory-structure-with-comments).

The open question, to which I couldn't find a solution is: how do I produce multiline comments to a file? Actually, I want to list a few lines of the file's content in there. Bonus: If I could even format the file contents with some kind of syntax highlighting (bash syntax), this would be perfect.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{%
  folder/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
  },
  file/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!5, bottom color=folderbg!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
  },
}
\forestset{%
  declare autowrapped toks={pic me}{},
  pic dir tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      folder,
      font=\itshape,
      grow'=0,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        edge label+/.option={pic me},
      },
    },
  },
  pic me set/.code n args=2{%
    \forestset{%
      #1/.style={%
        inner xsep=2\Size,
        pic me={pic {#2}},
      }
    }
  },
  pic me set={directory}{folder},
  pic me set={file}{file},
}
\newcommand{\fname}[2]{\begin{tabular}{m{1cm}@{\quad}m{4cm}}#1 & \normalfont#2\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  pic dir tree,
  where level=0{}{% folder icons by default; override using file for file icons
    directory,
  },
  [system
    [\fname{config}{A comment about this folder}
    ]
    [lib
      [Access
      ]
      [Plugin
      ]
      [\fname{file.txt}{A comment about this file}, file
      ]
    ]
    [templates
    ]
    [tests
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you just use a `minipage`? For example, `config\hspace{1cm}\begin{minipage}{4cm}{A comment about this folder that is very long.\newline Perhaps several lines.}\end{minipage}`

Comment: Essentially duplicate of [Table with multiple lines in some cells - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40561/table-with-multiple-lines-in-some-cells) because the code uses tabular on lower level, as you can tell

Comment: You can put `tabular` configuration into the options for all or some `forest` nodes. You don't need a separate macro. So put the first argument to `tabular` into the `forest` option and make `frame` a style rather than a macro.