# How can I present a project/directory structure when presenting code?

Tags: directory, dirtree

When preparing a presentation for a coding camp, I would like to display my directory structure
as the following

[image]

Could anyone suggest any existing templates may help, or the correct latex package that does the job?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site :) Perhaps the following might be a helpful starting point: [Making a (simple) directory tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree) and/or [Making a directory tree of folders and files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328886/making-a-directory-tree-of-folders-and-files). Perhaps you could take a look, and show us what you can produce, and then make your question a bit more specific? Welcome again! :)

Comment: happy to be in the community! I found it hard to find the right keywords. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the proposed package `dirtree`, a solution would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dirtree}

\begin{document}
\dirtree{%
    .1 project\_name/.
    .2 CMakeLists.txt.
    .2 build/.
    .2 bin/.
    .3 tools\_demo.
    .2 lib/.
    .3 libtools.a.
    .2 src/.
    .3 ....+
}
\end{document}
```

and compiled:

[image]