# listings - ! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I have to use unicode char in listings package, but error reported in below example:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "94.
```

How to resolve this error:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}
\newcounter{T}
\newcommand\makenode[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=0pt, remember picture] { 
        \node[anchor=base,#1/.try] (m-\the\value{T}) {#2};}%
    %\node[fill=red!10,label=\the\value{T},anchor=base,#1/.try] (m-\the\value{T}) {#2}; }%
    \stepcounter{T}%
}
\lstdefinelanguage{myLang}{
    alsoletter=0123456789\+\=\*\/<(){};\,
}
\lstset{
    identifierstyle=\makenode{identifier},
    inputencoding = utf8,  % Input encoding
    extendedchars = true,  % Extended ASCII
}
\lstset{label= ,caption= ,captionpos=b,numbers=left}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=myLang, numbers=none, escapechar=!,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries, linewidth=0.82\linewidth] 
    
    └── rootdir
    ├── product
    │   ├── app
    │   ├── etc
    │   └── priv-app
    ├── system
    │   ├── app
    │   ├── etc
    │   └── priv-app
    └── vendor
    ├── app
    ├── etc
    └── priv-app
    
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
    every edge/.append style = {->, thick, >=latex,
        line width = 1pt },
    box/.style = {align=center, minimum height = 0pt,inner sep=0,
        font = \bfseries},
    text width = 2.5cm ]
    \node[box,fit=(m-4)(m-6), draw] {};
    \foreach \x/\y in {18/6,21/9,25/13,18/29,21/31,25/34} {
        \draw[-latex] (m-\x) ..controls ([xshift=2cm]m-\x) (m-\y);
    }
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your document actually saved as UTF-8?

Comment: Since you’re using TikZ anyway, [consider this instead.](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/filesystem-tree/)

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328987/1952

Comment: Special case of [unicode - Having problems with listings and UTF-8. Can it be fixed? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed?noredirect=1&lq=1) I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, package `listings` does not support multi-byte encodings with 8-bit TeX engines.
Workarounds:

- As workaround package `listingsutf8` can be used, if the UTF-8 characters can be converted to the slots of a 8-bit encoding, supported by LaTeX. The environment `lstlistings` is not supported, the contents goes into a separate file that is
  read by `\lstinputlisting` with the correct encoding options. Then package `listingsutf8` automatically converts the file for package `listings`.

  The box drawing characters complicate the matters because the code page 437 has them, but `cp437.def` misses them.
- But maybe there is an easier way. Package `pmboxdraw` provides these characters, if
  you do not have a font that provides them with a `.dfu` file for LaTeX's UTF-8 support. If you do not need the features of package `listings` for this "ASCII art",
  then some of the verbatim environments will work (plain `verbatim`, package `verbatim`, package `alltt` with better escaping support, ...).

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}% standalone does not work in this case
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}% with proportional type writer font
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
└── rootdir
├── product
│   ├── app
│   ├── etc
│   └── priv-app
├── system
│   ├── app
│   ├── etc
│   └── priv-app
└── vendor
├── app
├── etc
└── priv-app
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

So, i had the same problem. An option was, to use `\begin{verbatim}`, but i realy liked to customize my listing e.g. with a caption. So what i did, was to add `\usepackage{pmboxdraw}` and in the listing `literate= ...`.
Example:

```
\documentclass{article}% standalone does not work in this case
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=myLang, caption=myCaption, label=lst:myLabel, numbers=none, escapechar=!, basicstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries, linewidth=0.82\linewidth,literate = {├}{{\textSFviii}}1 {─}{{\textSFx}}1 {└}{{\textSFii}}1 {│}{{\textSFxi}}1] 
        └── rootdir
        ├── product
        │   ├── app
        │   ├── etc
        │   └── priv-app
        ├── system
        │   ├── app
        │   ├── etc
        │   └── priv-app
        └── vendor
        ├── app
        ├── etc
        └── priv-app
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

All symbols can be found here: https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/contrib/pmboxdraw/pmboxdraw.pdf