# Latex Forest decorate parts of the text

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I'd like to have a diagram like in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270761/119210) answer:

[image: What I have]

The difference is, that the box shouldn't conatin *all* of the text, but *parts* of it. The text afterwards has to go undecorated.

I tried making the whole diagram plain and adding decoration manually, but it didn't compile.

I don't care about wich library is used to generate the tree.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you give also a rough representation of what you need?

Comment: Just imagine the coloured box of each node in the picture only contain the word "tex" and the "t1.1" being classic black on white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is virtually impossible to tell what you really want: you give no code and a description which doesn't make much sense. Apparently, you want to split words into a bit in a coloured box and a bit not in a coloured box, where the word being split is inexplicably always `text`. Oh, well.

[image: bizarre tree]

Looks bizarre to me, but I suppose it takes all sorts, if not necessarily the liquorice kind.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  my label/.style={
    label={[font=\sffamily]right:{#1}},
  },
  for tree={% addaswyd o gôd Gonzalo Medina: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270761/
    folder,
    font=\sffamily,
    text=white,
    minimum height=0.75cm,
    if level=0{fill=ForestGreen}{fill/.wrap pgfmath arg={SlateBlue#1}{int(4-(mod((level()-1),4)))}},
    rounded corners=4pt,
    grow'=0,
    edge={ForestGreen,rounded corners,line width=1pt},
    fit=band,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      split option={content}{:}{content,my label},
    }
  }
  [tex:t1
    [tex:t1.1
      [tex:t1.1.1
        [tex:t1.1.1.1
          [tex:t1.1.1.1.1]
          [tex:t1.1.1.1.2]
          [tex:t1.1.1.1.3]
        ]
      ]
      [tex:t1.1.2
        [tex:t1.1.2.1]
      ]
      [tex:t1.1.3
        [tex:t1.1.3.1]
      ]
    ]
    [tex:t1.2
      [tex:t1.2.1]
      [tex:t1.2.2]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.
I got the following errors while compiling:
"Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/forest/package@options/edges' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...fPackageOptions{/forest/package@options}"
"Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/split option', to which ys you misspelled it. \end{forest}"

Comment: @piegames Your TeX installation is out of date and you have an old version of Forest. You need to update.

Comment: Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340354/.