# forest with more than one main file

Tags: forest

I am using the following code to draw a folder tree:

```
%credit:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
%[
[text1    %this should be on the same level of...
  [text1.1
    [text1.1.1]
  ]
  [text1.2
    [text1.2.1]
  ]
]
[text2]   %...this
%]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The output is the following:

[image]

I do not understand why text2 does not appear.

My aim is to have text1 and text2 on the same level as two main files. The only solution I found is to uncomment the square brackets in the code above and obtain
[image]

But I would like to not have the vertical line on the left. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Have you considered using `edges`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Salim Bou's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349025/) is perfectly correct. However, it is now much easier to draw trees of this kind using Forest and it seems a shame not to make the most of the new facilities.

Current Forest (version 2 and later) supports libraries to extend its functionality, much as Ti*k*Z does. One of the bundled libraries is `edges` which, among other things, provides an out-of-the-box style for drawing trees of this kind. For some reason, it is called `folder`, but don't let that put you off. It even works OK on GNU/Linux and other Unix-ish systems!

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    folder,
    edge label={node [midway, inner sep=1.25pt, fill] {}},
  }
  [, phantom
    [text1
      [text1.1
        [text1.1.1]
      ]
      [text1.2
        [text1.2.1]
      ]
    ]
    [text2]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: directory tree the easy way]

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to hide first level with their edges by adding `phantom` key

```
%credit:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
[,phantom  % add this to hide first level 
[text1    
  [text1.1
    [text1.1.1]
  ]
  [text1.2
    [text1.2.1]
  ]
]
[text2]   
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using `edges`?