# How can I use menukeys inside a {forest} environment?

Tags: forest, menukeys

I'm trying to show a menu hierarchy in a diagram with graphical representations of keys using the `menukeys` and `forest` packages.
I have used the code from the following answer for formatting a forest the way that I would like it: [Making a (simple) directory tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree#270761)

The problem is that the `\keys{}` command doesn't work inside the forest.
how can I make it work?

From this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}
\section{Menu structure}

The menu can be navigated with the keyboard, from the main menu you can press \keys{A} to go the menu 2 or \keys{B} to go to menu 3.

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
[Main menu
  [ \keys{A} $\rightarrow$ Menu 2
    [Foo]
    [Bar]
    [Baz]
  ]
  [\keys{B} $\rightarrow$ Menu 3
    [Quux]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

I get this output:
[image: Output from code above]

Note that the keys are missing from the diagram, just before each `\rightarrow`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most likely caused by nesting `tikzpicture` environments. The simplest way to get around it would be to save your keys in `\sbox`es.

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdfLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\newsavebox{\keyA}
\sbox{\keyA}{\keys{A}}
\newsavebox{\keyB}
\sbox{\keyB}{\keys{B}}
\begin{document}
\section{Menu structure}

The menu can be navigated with the keyboard, from the main menu you can press \keys{A} to go the menu 2 or \keys{B} to go to menu 3.

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
[Main menu
  [ \usebox{\keyA} $\rightarrow$ Menu 2
    [Foo]
    [Bar]
    [Baz]
  ]
  [\usebox{\keyB} $\rightarrow$ Menu 3
    [Quux]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: You don't like the new-fangled `edge path'` then?

Comment: @cfr Unlike some people I don't have the intricacies of `forest` embedded in my brain. ;)

Comment: Bits you do, though. Like the `fit to` stuff I always forget. However, that bit, yes, is embedded in mine now. Mostly, because it is so much less typing :-).

Answer (score 1):

This is a supplement to [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423228/). It shows how to greatly simplify the code by using the `edges` library. If you have version 1 of Forest and cannot update, stick to the original code. Otherwise, the `edges` library offers a more flexible and robust solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\newsavebox{\keyA}
\sbox{\keyA}{\keys{A}}
\newsavebox{\keyB}
\sbox{\keyB}{\keys{B}}
\begin{document}
\section{Menu structure}

The menu can be navigated with the keyboard, from the main menu you can press \keys{A} to go the menu 2 or \keys{B} to go to menu 3.

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    folder, 
    grow'=0,
    edge label={node [midway, inner sep=1.25pt, fill] {}},
    font=\ttfamily,
  }
  [Main menu
    [ \usebox{\keyA} $\rightarrow$ Menu 2
      [Foo]
      [Bar]
      [Baz]
    ]
    [\usebox{\keyB} $\rightarrow$ Menu 3
      [Quux]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: directory structure with <code>edges</code> library]

Comment: That does look much simpler, I'll give it a go, thanks.