# Add a description to file structure

Tags: formatting, forest, alignment, dirtree

I would like to add a file structure to my document and be able to add a description to each directory/file. From another [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree) I got the file structure like this:

```
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        font=\ttfamily,
        grow'=0,
        child anchor=west,
        parent anchor=south,
        anchor=west,
        calign=first,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        before typesetting nodes={
            if n=1
            {insert before={[,phantom]}}
            {}
        },
        fit=band,
        before computing xy={l=15pt},
    }
    [text1
        [text1.1
            [text1.1.1 ... Here goes a description that could be multiple lines long]
            [some\_random\_file.txt ... This description is not aligned with the description above]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

There are two problems with my approach (just adding three dots and then the description)

The first is that when a description is to long it just continues the line instead of going into the next line.

The second is that descriptions are not alligned with each other. I tried to use `\tabto` but this doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone knows how to fix any of those problems or knows another was to make this look nice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{justtrees}% v 0.07
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \useforestlibrary{edges}
    \forestapplylibrarydefaults{edges}

\begin{document}
{
\tikzset{lbl/.style={text width=16em, align=left,
                     xshift=12pt, yshift=1ex, inner ysep=0pt,
                     font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                     anchor=north west}}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        font=\ttfamily,
        anchor=west,
        grow'=0,
        s sep+=13pt,  % 7pt if descritons has only 2 lines
        calign=first,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        before typesetting nodes={
            if n=1
            {insert before={[,phantom]}}
            {}
        },
        fit=band,
        before computing xy={l=15pt},
    }
    [text1
        [text1.1,
            [text1.1.1, name=A]
            [some\_random\_file.txt,name=B]
        ]
    ]
\node[lbl] at (A-|B.east) {Here goes a description that could be multiple lines long long long long long long long long long long};
\node[lbl] at (B.east)    {This description is not aligned with the description above};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Note: this solution need some manual tweak. If you have description longer or shorter than three lines, you need to change `s sep+` accordingly (increase/shortened).