# Forest package : URL tree?

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, trees

After reading this answer ([Making a (simple) directory tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree)), I was curious to see if I can reproduce this URL tree with the forest package :

[image]

As you can see, it is similar to a dirtree but some urls should be highlighted in blue.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to do that, except for punching in the texts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
highlight/.style={fill=cyan,fill opacity=0.4,rounded corners},
forked edges,
for tree={folder,grow'=0,font=\ttfamily,where n children=0{highlight}{}}
[question/
 [mes-exercises/
  [/]
  [unnecessary/]
  [\textunderscore id/]
 ]
 [mes-exercises/
  [/]
  [unnecessary/]
  [\textunderscore id/]
 ]
 [profil]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a tighter version thereof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
highlight/.style={fill=cyan,fill opacity=0.4,rounded corners,inner sep=1pt,
outer sep=1pt},
forked edges,
for tree={folder,grow'=0,font=\ttfamily,s sep=0.4ex,
    where n children=0{highlight}{}},
[question/
 [mes-exercises/
  [/]
  [unnecessary/]
  [\textunderscore id/]
 ]
 [mes-exercises/
  [/]
  [unnecessary/]
  [\textunderscore id/]
 ]
 [profil]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]