# Drawing Arrows Between Tikz Boxes Around Forest Nodes (w/ MWE + Screenshot)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, nodes, forest, trees

I am using MacTeX/TeXLive 2021, the newest version of TeXStudio, and Latexmk.

I would like to draw an arrow from the green box to the purple box in the picture below. It would replace the current pink arrow that goes from the node the green box code is in to the node the purple box code is in. (I want it to go ≈ -170:3cm from the green to -95:3cm from the purple. None of the arrow would be within either box—just from the green to the purple.) MWE is included below the image.

[image: MWE Screenshot of Current Result]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand{\xbar}[1]{\ensuremath{\overline{\textrm{#1}}}}

\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%%% Trees
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta,arrows,shapes.geometric,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}

\begin{document}
    
\hspace*{-4em}\scalebox{.7}{\begin{forest}
        for tree={s sep=7mm, inner sep=0, l*=1.75}
        [... \\ CP [VP,fit=band,name=frontedVP,tikz={\node (frontedVP) [draw,thick,RoyalPurple,inner sep=1.5mm,fit to=tree,name=frontedVP]{};} [VP [V \\ blah] [DP [D \\ $\varnothing$] [N \\ blahh]]] [VP [PP [blah blah,roof]] [VP [PP [\sout{blah blah blah blah},roof]] [VP [V \\ \sout{blah}] [DP [D \\ $\varnothing$] [N \\ \sout{blahh}]]]]]] [CP [\xbar{C} [C \\ $\varnothing$] [TP [DP [D \\ blah] [N \\ $\varnothing$]] [\xbar{T} [T \\ abc \\ $+$\textsc{blah}] [$\langle$VP$\rangle$,fit=band,name=VPprefronting,tikz={\node (VPprefronting) [draw,thick,PineGreen,inner sep=1.5mm, fit to=tree,name=VPprefronting]{};} [VP,name=firstmovedvp [V \\ \sout{blah}] [DP [D \\ $\varnothing$] [N \\ \sout{blahh}]]] [VP [PP [\sout{blah blah},roof]] [VP [$\langle$PP$\rangle$ [\sout{blah blah blah blah},roof,name=extraposedbase]] [VP,name=lowvp [V \\ \sout{blah}] [DP [D \\ $\varnothing$] [N \\ \sout{blahh}]]]]]]]]] [PP [blah blah blah blah,roof,name=extraposedsurface]]]]
        \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=2.5mm,width=2.5mm]},blue] (lowvp)..controls +(south east:14cm) and +(south west:11cm)..(firstmovedvp);
        \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=2.5mm,width=2.5mm]},blue] (extraposedbase)..controls +(-60:9cm) and +(-35:22cm)..(extraposedsurface);
        \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=2.5mm,width=2.5mm]},Magenta] (VPprefronting)..controls +(-160:12cm) and +(-95:15cm)..(frontedVP);
\end{forest}}
    
\end{document}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `draw tree tikz processing order/.nodewalk style=tree children-first` to the tree preamble. Why? Forest first draws the nodes, then their edges, then any additional `tikz` commands attached to the nodes; by default, it does so  by a depth-first, children-first traversal of the tree. However, this means that we are attempting to draw the arrows between the `fit`ted boxes before those boxes are created (even if the code for the arrows is given last, we draw the arrows in the context of the root node; and the fit boxes are obviously drawn at VPs). The suggested addition to the preamble changes the order to children-first (for the `tikz` additions), so the boxes are drawn before the arrows and all is well. (Below, I have also removed the redundant node `name`s.)

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand{\xbar}[1]{\ensuremath{\overline{\textrm{#1}}}}

\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%%% Trees
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta,arrows,shapes.geometric,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}

\begin{document}
    
\hspace*{-4em}\scalebox{.7}{\begin{forest}
    for tree={s sep=7mm, inner sep=0, l*=1.75},
    draw tree tikz processing order/.nodewalk style=tree children-first,
    [... \\ CP [VP,fit=band,tikz={\node (frontedVP) [draw,thick,RoyalPurple,inner sep=1.5mm,fit to=tree]{};} [VP [V \\ blah] [DP [D \\ $\varnothing$] [N \\ blahh]]] [VP [PP [blah blah,roof]] [VP [PP [\sout{blah blah blah blah},roof]] [VP [V \\ \sout{blah}] [DP [D \\ $\varnothing$] [N \\ \sout{blahh}]]]]]] [CP [\xbar{C} [C \\ $\varnothing$] [TP [DP [D \\ blah] [N \\ $\varnothing$]] [\xbar{T} [T \\ abc \\ $+$\textsc{blah}] [$\langle$VP$\rangle$,fit=band,tikz={\node (VPprefronting) [draw,thick,PineGreen,inner sep=1.5mm, fit to=tree]{};} [VP,name=firstmovedvp [V \\ \sout{blah}] [DP [D \\ $\varnothing$] [N \\ \sout{blahh}]]] [VP [PP [\sout{blah blah},roof]] [VP [$\langle$PP$\rangle$ [\sout{blah blah blah blah},roof,name=extraposedbase]] [VP,name=lowvp [V \\ \sout{blah}] [DP [D \\ $\varnothing$] [N \\ \sout{blahh}]]]]]]]]] [PP [blah blah blah blah,roof,name=extraposedsurface]]]]
    \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=2.5mm,width=2.5mm]},blue] (lowvp)..controls +(south east:14cm) and +(south west:11cm)..(firstmovedvp);
    \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=2.5mm,width=2.5mm]},blue] (extraposedbase)..controls +(-60:9cm) and +(-35:22cm)..(extraposedsurface);
    \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=2.5mm,width=2.5mm]},Magenta] (VPprefronting)..controls +(-160:12cm) and +(-95:15cm)..(frontedVP);
  \end{forest}}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: When the boss comes, the job is done... :-)

Comment: Thank you so much!!