# Latex Forest package - making a directory tree with a description of each folder

Tags: forest

I've got this code from the user [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree) and it looks great, it's exactly what I want. However I would like to add a description of each folder that can be a rather long test, like for instance in the "config" node bellow.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}

\def\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{
  folder/.pic={
    \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
      (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);  
    \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
      (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    inner xsep=7pt,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor) pic {folder} \forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }  
[system
  [config: this text is sooooo long oh not it won't fit in the page help me please
  ]
  [lib
    [Access
    ]
    [Plugin
    ]
  ]
  [templates
  ]
  [tests
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The result that I get is this:
[image: Problem with long descriptions]

I would like that the text automatically went to a new line.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the width of the text. For example using  `text width=8cm`

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}

\def\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{
    folder/.pic={
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
        (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);  
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
        (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
    }
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            font=\ttfamily,
            text width=8cm,% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            grow'=0,
            child anchor=west,
            parent anchor=south,
            anchor=west,
            calign=first,
            inner xsep=7pt,
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
                (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor) pic {folder} \forestoption{edge label};
            },
            before typesetting nodes={
                if n=1
                {insert before={[,phantom]}}
                {}
            },
            fit=band,
            before computing xy={l=15pt},
        }  
        [system
        [config: this text is sooooo long oh not it won't fit in the page help me please
        ]
        [lib
        [Access
        ]
        [Plugin
        ]
        ]
        [templates
        ]
        [tests
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

UPDATE after follow up question.

This is another way:

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\definecolor{folderbg}{RGB}{124,166,198}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}

\def\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{
    folder/.pic={
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
        (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);  
        \filldraw[draw=folderborder,top color=folderbg!50,bottom color=folderbg]
        (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
    }
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            font=\ttfamily,
            grow'=0,
            child anchor=west,
            parent anchor=south,
            anchor=west,
            calign=first,
            inner xsep=7pt,
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
                (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- (.child anchor) pic {folder} \forestoption{edge label};
            },
            before typesetting nodes={
                if n=1
                {insert before={[,phantom]}}
                {}
            },
            fit=band,
            before computing xy={l=15pt},
        }  
        [system
        [config: \parbox{7cm}{this text is sooooo long oh not it won't fit in the page help me please}% changed
        ]
        [lib
        [Access
        ]
        [Plugin
        ]
        ]
        [templates
        ]
        [tests
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yup, that did the trick!
For style points, is there any way that "config" stays at the same line as the folder icon?

Comment: @MooDoesCow Please see the updated answer.