# How to control the vertical space between the parent and the first child inside a forest environment

Tags: forest

Based on the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270761/278762 from @GonzaloMedina.
How can I control the vertical space `y` shown in the picture below

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
[text1
  [text1.1
    [text1.1.1]
    [text1.1.2]
    [text1.1.3]
  ]
  [text1.2
    [text1.2.1]
    [text1.2.2]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the spacing for all the children of `text1.1`, you can simply change `s sep`:

```
[text1
  [text1.1, s sep=1cm
    [text1.1.1]
    [text1.1.2]
    [text1.1.3]
  ]
```

[image]

On the other hand, if you only want to change the spacing above `text 1.1.1`, then you can add `yshift=` to the node:

[image]

```
[text1
  [text1.1
    [text1.1.1, yshift=-1.5cm]
    [text1.1.2]
    [text1.1.3]
  ]
```

If you want to do this for all the `x.x.1` nodes, you can add it to the `for tree`:

`if n children=0{if n=1{yshift=-1.5cm}{}}{}`

[image]

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
    if n children=0{if n=1{yshift=-1.5cm}{}}{}
  }
[text1
  [text1.1
    [text1.1.1]
    [text1.1.2]
    [text1.1.3]
  ]
  [text1.2
    [text1.2.1]
    [text1.2.2]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!